# Should I flag a question as duplicate if it has received better answers?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

Should I flag a question as a duplicate if it has already received **better answer(s)** than the original question?

If I do flag the duplicate, people are/may be more likely to visit the original question and therefore will miss out on the better answer(s) on the duplicate question.

Comment: Users who are not logged in, especially, will be automatically redirected to the original question without ever getting a chance to see the duplicate beyond its title and excerpt (unless they put `?noredirect` in the URL, but you know). I'm not sure if it accounts for duplicate questions with answers though.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha

Comment: @BoltClock dupes with answers don't get redirected - I just tested: opening [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/why-does-a-question-appear-as-modified-by-the-community-user) when I am not logged in landed in right there, there was no redirect

Comment: @gnat Thanks! I suppose that would mean we should flag the older question as a duplicate when the newer one has better answers, then. Perhaps you should post an answer with information from the question you shared?

Comment: @JWLim [there you go](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252017/839601) - posted this as an answer

Answer (score 74, accepted):

[This guidance at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/165773) recommends to favor better questions and better answers:

> If the new question is a better question or has better answers, then vote to close the old one as a duplicate of the new one.
>
> You can flag and ask a moderator to merge after closure if they're *exactly* the same.
>
> If they differ based on the versions of the relevant systems, then they're not really *exact* duplicates - make sure this is indicated in the questions themselves, and provide cross-links so folks looking for one but finding the other have a path to the correct answers.

In the event that a question with better/more complete answers is closed as a duplicate of a question with worse/less complete answers, you can resolve that issue by flagging for a moderator, posting a question on Meta referencing the issue, or visiting the [SOCVR Chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and requesting assistance with a re-open/re-close ritual (with support from Gold Tag Badge holders who wield their dupe hammers).

Comment: Also, sometimes you can nudge one/both questions a bit (mostly by broadening them), so they are obvious exact duplicates afterwards. Makes merging much more likely.

Comment: I often suspect if this principle is fair to the owner of the older question, since if a question is closed as duplicate, the notice suggests Op can edit the question to look more differently, it acts as if throwing the responsibility of avoiding duplicates from the OP of the newer question to the OP of the older question, and also in my experience duplicates often attract downvotes

Comment: @amuse I think [it is fair and ethical](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/331608/839601): "...since duplicate has better answers to their question, it looks fair and ethical to refer them to these better answers as well... if the OP has asked better question than dupe target, it will appear in web searches instead of target and - please note - system won't automatically redirect to target users with enough rep to upvote, meaning they would be able to vote on the good question before getting to the dupe with better answers (at least that's how I myself do...) "

Comment: All in all, [Clonological](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clonological) isn't necessarily => Chronological.

Comment: Is it possible to edit this? I found 2 duplicates who were inverted and flagged a moderator (I didn't have access to chatroom because of network restriction) and I got this as an answer "Moderator flags must not be used to resolve issues with dupe closures. @ping the gold badge user who closed the question in the comments and inform them the same. ". To avoid more people flagging this to the mod and disturbing them, it should be edited

Comment: @JackRed it is possible that decline reason means you didn't explain in flag message why you picked flagging over chat and posting to meta. Mods can't read your mind and tell your reasons if you don't write them. On a related note, flag message should also cover reasons why you think one dupe is better than another - mods won't just take your word that it's better and will decline as insufficient evidence

Comment: I understand that (and you're right I didn't explained why I didn't pick chat). However I detailed it well (as much as I can with the character limit) (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387791/should-these-two-questions-one-duplicate-of-the-other-be-inverted). I gave, i think, enough detail for the request to be handled, however even if it's the not case the answer shouldn't have been "Moderator flags must not be used to resolve issues with dupe closures", and rather "the provided detail aren't enough for us to take action".  However we can ask directly a mod if we should flag or not

Comment: Maybe not remove it. But change it to say that the flag should be the last resort and a meta post/ping to user in the chat|directly in the comment should be preferred. I think it could be better