# Which question is the better reference for a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I found sometimes that old questions are marked and closed as duplicate of new questions. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2384078/2886003) is an example, where a question of 2010 is marked as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18387938/2886003) of one asked in 2013.

I [found](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers) that this is because the site encourages better answers of the exact same questions.
But **what makes a better answer**? In one the selected [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2384139/2886003) has more votes than the more [recent one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18388016/2886003), but this one has references to the documentation explicitly.

I'm asking because I was looking for duplicates of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11767867/2886003) in 2012 which asked the same thing. Which one should I mark as a duplicate?

Comment: The question I relate about hasn't received better answers of duplicates.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Answer (score 13):

For the best benefit of the long term users of the site - choose the question with the **best** answer as the one that has been duplicated.

Age doesn't matter here - quality of answer (and to some extent, question) is the overriding concern here.

Comment: Oh, sorry I wanted to ask also for the quality of the answers. See my edit

Comment: @Llopis - unfortunately quality is a rather subjective thing... Votes don't tell you anything about quality (an older post is likely to collect more votes than a younger one, for instance). It is a judgement call.

Answer (score 4):

In general, here are the criteria we use.

The canonical question should:

- Have the best answer (counted by completeness, upvotes, and generality)
- Have the most views (if two questions meet the above)
- Have the best written question content (most general; most complete)

Other questions should be closed as a duplicate of the canonical question, and if possible, merged.

Comment: Should we take into account the fact that it has a chosen answer or if OP is active ? I marked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41714319/calculating-age-using-mutate-with-lubridate-functions as a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611314/calculating-ages-in-r/47529507#47529507 because it had a higher score, but OP didn't select any answer and hasn't been active since 2012 so new better answers cannot be selected, so not sure if it was the right choice.