# Not-a-dupe flag rejected by moderator for "lack of evidence"

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, declined-flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793868/get-all-variables-from-a-php-file-without-initializing-it) as not-a-dupe after it was marked as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562936/find-all-php-variables-with-preg-match). Here's the excerpt in my flag history:

> If this is a duplicate, it is certainly the more general of the two. The older question restricts possible answers in a way that's not likely to be as instructive or helpful as possible. – kojiro Jul 17 at 3:11 *declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it*

I am asking the community to weigh back in on this, because I strongly disagree with the moderator's decision. I have two arguments:

1. While we generally encourage the community to choose the more correct of a pair of duplicates on the basis of [which has the best *answer*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252929/which-question-is-the-better-reference-for-a-duplicate), closing a question as a duplicate too soon prevents us from posting better answers. This is such a case, as the one question has had nine months to gather upvotes and the other had about 20 minutes before it was closed.
2. Another important criteria for choosing overall post quality is how general it is. Too-specific questions lead to too-specific answers, and those are less valuable and educational for StackOverflow visitors. In this case, [the not-specifically-regex question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793868/get-all-variables-from-a-php-file-without-initializing-it) is clearly the more general of the two questions. In fact, at least two upvoted comments suggest that [the regex question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562936/find-all-php-variables-with-preg-match) is actually an attempt [to apply a hammer to screws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument).

The younger question has a more findable, more general title and content, and has a chance to have better answers than the older question with its requirement to use regular expressions. Please help me reevaluate which is the better of the two.

Comment: How does one flag a question as `not-a-dupe`?

Comment: @geoidesic I mean I flagged it for moderator attention because I believe it had been wrongly marked as a dupe.