# Which question should be marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

In searching for something else I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/179102/1111886) which is virtually the same as [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9273629/1111886) I answered awhile back.

I know from [this meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252930/1111886) that I should mark the one that has the "best answer". While one has an answer that has 25 upvotes, it does not answer the question as I see it. The answer to the other question however is my own, so it feels a bit inappropriate for me to declare it the best answer by flagging the other post.

Comment: If I were just voting to close as a dupe I'd tend to pick the earlier one to keep.  (After all, it wasn't a dupe when it was written.)  But if the later one is significantly better written or has better answers then I don't think I'd flag either -- just cross-link.

Comment: @HotLicks: Only use age as a tie-breaker, so when all else is equal. Bad posts do not become better by stewing a long time, and another posts relative newness does not stop it from potentially being better.

Comment: @Deduplicator - Except that saying an older question is a dupe of a newer one is essentially libel.  It says that the person who wrote the first question did not adequately search for a dupe before posting, which is clearly false.

Comment: @HotLicks: Nope. This is a duplicate already having an answer (insert target), does not in any way say or imply which one was posted first.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel that two questions are duplicates and both of them have answers worth keeping around then flag one of the questions and indicate to a moderator that you feel that the questions should be merged, rather than just closed as a duplicate, because they both have answer of value.

Comment: I forget that that is an option as I do not think I have enough rep to merge myself.

Comment: You don't have enough reputation to flag the post for moderator attention?  That takes 15 rep.  You have 1,387 more rep than you actually need.

Comment: I meant I don't have enough rep to merge, and thus forget that others can do it.

Comment: @Fr33dan Nobody has enough rep to merge posts.  Only moderators can merge posts.

Comment: The flagging process doesn't have any way to indicate that I think they should be merged. The text at the top indicates "Flagging > _Closing_ > Duplicate" so I just did exactly what I was trying to avoid doing...

Comment: Flagging for merging is not common, that's why it needs a custom flag.