# Why the older question considered as the duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I just see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557727/qsettingsiniformat-values-with-returned-as-qstringlist) that created only today and this [older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052930/how-to-read-a-value-using-qsetting-if-the-value-contains-comma-character) that created a **year** ago. The older is marked as duplicate with a link going to the newer post. Why it is considered as duplicate even it is older than the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which question is the better reference for a duplicate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252929/which-question-is-the-better-reference-for-a-duplicate) and of [Should I flag a question as duplicate if it has received better answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers)

Comment: @gnat: True. Considering the fact that the answerer is the only close voter, this might need some follow up.

Comment: The recursion on this hurts my eyes...

Answer (score 6):

I am not an expert  in that tag, but is seems the newer answer is better than the older one. That would justify closing the older one.

A thing that bothers me it that it is closed by the one answering the newest question which might *feel* like closing for this own benefit (I am definitely not say he did! Let him clarify. I just pinged him so he knows about this post)

Comment: Yeah I think it is unfair on the older one. But we will see.

Comment: @reggie_jimac Fairness has nothing to do with it. Relevance has everything to do with it. If the older question is out of date and the newer question is more up to date and more relevant, then the older question might as well be closed as a duplicate of the newer. It's a marker to help find relevant information, not a punishment.

Comment: @J.Steen: I agree with your first comment. Closing as duplicate is often seen as something bad, while it is a very effective mechanism to get the best information together.

Comment: You know that for duplicate-closing, *the question* should be considered, **not** any answers? Also, one can flag for merging where appropriate.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I would never close a question as a dup of another if the dup has poor answers. I would close it the other way around.

Comment: So, you wouldn't close as duplicate of the better question (even though it has worse answers), and then flag for merging? (I actually don't consider the old one to be better in this case though.)

Comment: @Deduplicator: I would probably edit the question into shape. My experience is that most mods aren't really liking to merge questions.