# Is it ethical to mark older questions as a duplicate of newer one?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

From [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938), I know we should mark older questions as duplicate of new one if the new one has better answers, but actually I doubt if this policy is appropriate because I think it is unfair to OP of the older question, consider a case:

1. A has a question , which searched at this site for long time and cannot find duplicates, then ask the question here
2. B has a question which is duplicate of A, but ask without searching before
3. Later, B's question has better answers and A's question is marked as the duplicate of B's

At here, the one who doesn't show search effort is B, not A, if we marked A's question as duplicate, is it misguide people that A lacks search effort instead of B? And also, from [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254712) post, duplicates are more likely to be downvoted, does this policy brings innocent downvotes to OP of older questions?

So my question is, is marking older questions as duplicate unfair to OP of older questions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure we have a dupe for this question here. In general its considered OK IIRC.

Comment: Generally the goal is to present the content in the best possible way. Chronology is largely irrelevant to that goal.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315472/old-question-marked-as-duplicate-of-a-new-question and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280726/why-the-older-question-considered-as-the-duplicate

Comment: [This is actually done on Meta Stack Exchange.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/86997?lq=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all: please don't let "fairness" to a community member alter your judgement in any way. There is nothing unfair about content being managed so that it is the most optimal.

Secondly: duplicates being robo-downvoted is a wrong reason to downvote. The fact that people do it should absolutely not deter you from marking something as a duplicate - its not your fault, you did the right thing. Problems need to be solved, not avoided.

Answer (score 1):

It is fair and ethical to refer web search visitors to the question that [has received better answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251938/839601).

It would be unfair and unethical to do the other way round - that is, to refer them to the question that has received worse answers.

As for the OP, since duplicate has better answers to their question, it looks fair and ethical to refer them to these better answers as well.

Comment: The only thing that seems to remain a bit unfair and unethical is the rep of the OP. For those who care about it...

Comment: @Trilarion if the OP has asked better _question_ than dupe target, it will appear in web searches instead of target and - please note - system won't automatically redirect to target users with enough rep to upvote, meaning they would be able to vote on the good question before getting to the dupe with better answers (at least that's how I myself do when I get to SO from my google searches)

Comment: Many do it to "game" the system, I've seen several times where the person marking an old question as dupe, points to a new question he himself asked/answered in order to boost "rep"... *shrug*