# Duplicate questions which are in the same quality, but only the newer one is protected

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions, protected-questions

Please see these duplicate questions. The [older one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310223/what-does-this-mean-public-name-get-set) has asked in 2009-08-21. The [newer one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096926/what-is-the-get-set-syntax-in-c) has asked in 2011-02-23. The Stack Overflow Community has managed to protect the newer question but not the older one. Is it is based on the upvotes?

According to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280726/why-the-older-question-considered-as-the-duplicate) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252929/which-question-is-the-better-reference-for-a-duplicate). it is obvious that we should give the priority to the better-asked question regardless of the age of the question but in this case, I personally feel like there is no such difference.

Someone has marked the older question as the duplicate. That is not fair at all.

Comment: Why is this an issue for you? What is unfair about this? Do you understand fully what "protecting" a question implies? It looks like only the newer one attracted a lot of low-quality answers and spam, and that's probably the reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one is protected because there are lots of deleted answers and the system auto-protects to prevent more; that's it.

Comment: I am sorry if I wasted your valuable time. I did not see any deleted answers. I believe that it is because of the fewer privileges.

Comment: No worries; I was sipping rye whisky at a bar while writing this, so time well-spent. It may be that we should explain the Protect feature a bit more thoroughly to prevent such confusion.