# Should these two questions (one duplicate of the other) be inverted?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I was searching some information about regular expressions, and I found this question: *[Regular expression to stop at first match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match)* which is referenced as a duplicate. After looking at it briefly, I moved to the original (*[My regex is matching too much. How do I make it stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop)*) thinking that, if the duplicate has these many votes, the original should have a lot of interesting answers.

And it's not the case. While the accepted answers are more or less similar, the duplicate one is slightly more detailed and there are more others answers. And the duplicate has 10 times more views and upvotes on the question and answers.

I am not an experienced user of Stack Overflow, but I suppose the duplicate should be inverted. Should it?

Comment: I pinged the gold badge holder under that question to point them to this meta.

Comment: The dupe was asked 2 years later.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the duplicate is recent though. I don't see how the age of the question is important here

Comment: What do you mean by *"others answers"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen probably "various answers", that is answers that give other approaches than the common one both accepted answers do highlight. I'll let you pick a better wording though, my English capacities being very low.

Comment: @PeterMortensen yeah it's what Kaiido said. It wasn't my first reason for changing the duplicate, because non user shouldn't be redirected to a question less 'popular'. But when I read it seems to me that the answer were more diversified (pretty much all the same though)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the older question considered as the duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280726/why-the-older-question-considered-as-the-duplicate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reversed this duplicate closure. 
When choosing a duplicate target: the age of the post is irrelevant, 
it's the quality of the post.

This is determined by

- views
- upvotes
- number of answers
- answer quality (usually determined by upvotes)

[Regular expression to stop at first match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match) clearly exceeds on those points over [My regex is matching too much. How do I make it stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop?noredirect=1)