# Gold badge reopening a duplicate that I believe shouldn't be reopened

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer, tag-badges

I asked [Should these two questions (one duplicate of the other) be inverted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387791/should-these-two-questions-one-duplicate-of-the-other-be-inverted) last summer.

Tl;DR: 2 questions, A duplicate of B, but A has way more vote/view than B. Answer from moderator: duplicate should be inverted, and inverted it. (Nb: people told me that instead of going on meta, contacting the gold owner would have been better).

I recently saw the questions again ([My regex is matching too much. How do I make it stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop)) and it wasn't a duplicate anymore. I didn't realize at this time I could check the historic and thought it was strange but didn't think of it. So I flagged it as duplicate, but it aged away.

Recently I stumbled on the question again, and check the historic, seeing that the question was reopened the very day after the moderator changed it last year.

When contacting the gold badge in comment, he gave me some reason like *"a question is the duplicate of another thought, But the semantic in the title is different"*. And then deleted his comment after I answered.

So, on one hand he is the gold badge who flagged a question as duplicate, so I understand that as a gold badge he has the power and so I cannot really protest, but if I ask the question here, it's because I didn't get a real reason why the duplicate was deleted, when even the user said it's one.

As I tried to contact him and then a mod but it didn't work, I am asking meta, what should I do here? I *know* the gold user have the power but I feel like it's badly used here

Comment: The TL;DR answer is you get it closed again. That person cannot reopen the question again if that happens