# Should I move my answer to a new duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

I answered this question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392715/overlapping-buttons-prevent-button-from-raising-on-touch/36414403#36414403.

Although not the best question, and could have been written better, it was answerable. I answered it.

Today, [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425626/dont-bring-button-to-foreground-on-click/36429321#36429321) was posted, basically a duplicate of the one I answered yesterday, but written better and has 6 upvotes.

Per [this Meta.SE answer by Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha/147651#147651), it could be appropriate to flag yesterdays question as a duplicate of today's question. Which is fine by me.

But what about my answer? The one from yesterday is an accepted answer, so I can't delete it, and posting it again on today's question feels a bit wrong to me.

What would be the appropriate action to take in this case? Flag today's question as duplicate? Answer today's question and flag yesterday's as duplicate?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with deleting your "old" answer and putting it on the new question. Perhaps leave a comment on the old question to let them know you moved your answer (in case the duplicate flag doesn't go through, for whatever reason).

Comment: I can't delete the "old" answer because it's an accepted answer.

Comment: I think you can ask to merge questions (probably with "other" flag on your answer)... Hopefully someone knows proper steps to do that.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, I could do that. But I would like consensus on your decision. Dare to post an answer here?

Comment: If the new question is a duplicate of the other one where you answered, you should only *flag the new one as Duplicate*. Now, *if* the questions are actually different and would need a different answer, then you can answer with a new, tailored answer to the question. In any case, you shouldn't post duplicate *answers*. :)

Comment: @EricD, OK. I haven't posted a duplicate answer (well I did, but I deleted right away because I agree with you on that). However the new question is better than the old, which is why I am hesitant to flag it as a dupe. If either should be closed, I think it should be the question from yesterday.

Comment: I'm not a fan of closing as dupe an old question *to* a new one, it feels awkward, but why not. I prefer the other way: new to old. // If the new question is better in the sense that it would allow for a better answer, then you can answer! Just don't answer the same thing as the other answer, refer to the old one with a link and *add* new information. Well, I think you get the idea of what I'm saying: let's avoid crating duplicates in any way, when in the meantime I and others are working hard to *find and close* the existing ones. :)

Comment: @EricD, Alright. I posted a slightly more detailed answer on the new question. Flag the old question as dupe? Or link to the new question as "related"?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no rule that requires to use older question as duplicate target. - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252929/which-question-is-the-better-reference-for-a-duplicate

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Of course. It's just my preference. I've already done it both ways, I just prefer new -> old.

Comment: @EricD, Understood it's just opinion. You could post an answer here and see what types of votes is pulls in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't move your answer.

Flag (or if you have enough rep, vote) to close the older question as a duplicate of the newer, better one. There's nothing that says that duplicates *have* to be older.

Then when the question is closed flag the duplicate (i.e. the one you answered) to be **merged** into the master (i.e. the newer, better one). This will move your answer to the master question and permanently redirect links to the old question to become links to the new question.

Comment: I can't flag the older one as dupe. It has an accepted answer and the new one has no accepted or upvoted answers...

Comment: @CaptJak - ah, the one drawback. You *could* raise a custom flag, but you'd have to explain exactly why you were doing so.

Comment: I raised a custom flag, gave a brief explanation and linked this meta question.

Comment: Does merging actually ever happen? I have never come across a question marked as merged. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277979/give-ability-to-move-own-answer-from-duplicate-to-canonical-question

Comment: @Readwald as a regular user you don't see the merge stub, you're automatically redirected to the target question. One thing to look out for is answers older than the question.

Comment: 5 days later, flag still pending....

Comment: @CaptJak Flags aren't necessarily handled instantly. All sorted now.