# Newer, better question marked as a duplicate instead of the old one

Tags: discussion

After reading [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252929/which-question-is-the-better-reference-for-a-duplicate) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha/147651#147651) (I also checked if my current question was a duplicate, but as it is a specific case, I am not sure. Feel free to close if it is a duplicate.), the conclusion is that we should always chose a better question or a question having better answers over another one having poor/no answers or a lower quality.

However, I stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318491/building-meta-toolchain-qt5-with-qtwebengine-support) which is marked as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307460/building-qt-with-qtwebengine). In this case, I think the duplicate should be **the other question**, because :

- both questions have 1 upvote;
- the question marked as a duplicate is the one having an accepted answer, score of 2;
- the duplicate reason state that *This question has been asked before and already has an answer*, but it is not the case (or maybe the answer was deleted).

I just can guess that a user will be redirected to the good question more easily if we "switch" the duplicated question.

Am I wrong? If not, what can be done in this case? I don't think this is an uncommon case, and I'd like to know how it could be handled.

---

Update : The duplicate on these questions has now been switched. It seems better that way, since a new (or not) user can be redirected to the question having a practical answer.

Comment: Normally you can't mark a question as a duplicate of another one which has no answers, but in this case it *is* possible because the same user asked the same question twice.

Comment: @Glorfindel Understood. Shouldn't the duplicate be on the other question though?

Comment: Yes, maybe you can ask the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to help - it takes a couple of 3k users to reopen the question, and close the other one.

Comment: As I understand, post age doesn't matter for duplicates but the post quality. It's strange that in this case the better post was marked as a duplicate of the worse question.

Comment: Yes for me it has sense to switch (the otherone has answer and more info), then if the reopened question should stay open or not I can't judge since I know little about this technology