# What should we do with duplicate questions that return high in search results?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

It looks like when a question is flagged "duplicate", nobody can add new answers to it, which creates a problem with outdated answers, especially if the duplicate ranks higher in search results than the "correct" question.

For example, I just googled for "NumPy remove duplicate rows from matrix" and got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097247) as the top result. The problem is that that question is flagged as a duplicate and the accepted answer is no longer correct.

I didn't realize that until I spent some time researching the problem myself. Now I know that when I see a question flagged "duplicate", I better check the linked question, or I might get bogus information.  And, of course, I'm unable to add an answer to the duplicate question to correct it.

One possibility would be to figure out how to put an HTML tag on a page that points a search engine to a different, preferred page. I don't know how to do this, but it seems worth investigating, especially for somebody at Stack Overflow with the ability to actually change the server code.

Comment: If you are logged in, you get to see the duplicate you found via google. If you are not logged in, you get redirected to the post's dupe target. So, in principle, it should be enough to keep the dupe target up to date (that one hopefully isn't closed itself). For logged in users - they'll have to follow the link to the dupe target(s).

Comment: Nothing? Why do we need to do anything? Duplicates act as signposts to direct people towards a "canonical" answer.

Comment: You could suggest an edit to the accepted answer to point to the duplicate target, I suppose, but that would likely be rejected. I mean, the question you landed on had a big banner across the top with **This question already has an answer here:** and a link to the duplicate target. We *want* users to find the duplicate, but to go to the duplicate target to find the answer. If one chooses to ignore the banner... well, that's kind of on them, isn't it?

Comment: @Ethan Field, it's confusing to the reader to see an answer marked "accepted" that isn't correct.  Perhaps accepted checkmarks could be stripped from duplicate questions.

Comment: I've been a member of Stack Overflow for over seven years.  It was never clear to me until yesterday that the answers to "duplicated" questions could be flat out wrong with no way to correct them.

Comment: Accepted answers can be flat out wrong in general because acceptance only indicates which answer best helped the asker.

Comment: If the old top-voted accepted answer was correct for older versions but is no longer correct for newer versions, and you are *100% sure* of it, I think editing it to distinguish that would make the answer a lot less confusing, without running afoul of rules, eg *For versions X and below, you may:...*

Comment: Very unclear what exactly is proposed in addition to the current behavior - 302 for non-logged in users, huge (also presumably invisible) banners "answer is there"...

Comment: @BrentBaccala why did you say that you can't correct existing answer on duplicate question? Duplicates are not locked - so if you feel that answer on closed question need some edits you can definitely propose them... (also I'd question why would you need to do that - improving answers on target question would be more appropriate from my point of view)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I didn't understand until reading these comments that non-logged in users get a 302!  Really, what I was proposing was exactly that behavior.  Maybe I (and others) need to be educated about the effects of logging in to StackExchange sites.  Also, when I say that I can't correct the answer, I mean that I can't add a new answer.  I'm reluctant to edit existing answers like CertainPerformance suggests, though it's certainly a useful suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

The only reason we keep duplicate questions is for acting as search magnets. It seems that the question you mentioned fulfills this purpose. No further action is required. You can ignore the answers to duplicate questions and directly click what follows after "This question already has an answer here:". There, hopefully, you will get good answers.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on the search results (Stack Overflow vs Google vs Bing), we can always reverse the duplicate.  In general we want the question that is easiest to find to be the canonical question; with caveats.

From [a question about which question should be canonical and which should be marked as a duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252934/16587):

> The canonical question should:
>
> - Have the best answer (counted by completeness, upvotes, and generality)
> - Have the most views (if two questions meet the above)
> - Have the best written question content (most general; most complete)
>
> Other questions should be closed as a duplicate of the canonical question, and if possible, merged.

Comment: In this case it seems alright, the target has many more views than the duplicate. But we might want to make a search identifying such potential duplicate reversals.