# What should you do if nobody answers your question? Can you repost it?

Tags: discussion, support

If nobody answers your question and a month has gone by what should you do apart from offer a bounty? Should you delete the question and then re-write it as a new question?

Comment: Deleting and reposting questions will eventually get you banned from asking more questions. Please add more details to the existing question instead.

Comment: Is this documented in the help center, something like "What should I do if no one answers my question?"  A couple of meta topics today show users think deleting and reposting is the right course of action, which we should try to correct.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Most new users come from forums, where that *is* the correct course of action.  Given that most people confuse SE with forums at first glance, they believe it's what they should do.  Another one of those issues with new users not reading what is put in front of them.

Comment: That was posted more than 2 years **later** after this one. So it is not logic to mark this one as a duplicate, but maybe the other instead. @gnat

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ hmm, the opposite direction possibly makes better sense here - not because of age [because it doesn't matter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251938/839601) but because answers seem to look better

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Should you delete the question and then re-write it as a new question?

**No.** You should edit it and update it and add as much relevant detail as possible to make it the best possible question it can be. Note that this will [bump](/questions/tagged/bump) it back to the active questions, which is why reposting is never necessary.

If that fails to attract the desired attention, post a bounty on it.

Comment: Does editing the post also bump the question back to the tag pages?

Comment: @Ferrybig yes it does, [as explained in tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bump/info)

Answer (score 3):

There is an article in [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). It's [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Basically, one should first increase the quality of the question, make sure that there is [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (you can easily suggest it to the OP by adding `[mcve]` in comment).

In the end, one could [offer a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to provide extra reputation for answering the question.