# Re-asking a deleted post

Tags: discussion

I posted a question that has not had any answers. To make the question easy to get noticed i want to re-ask it. I deleted the original question, but when i tried to ask it again i got the error message:

> "This post appears to be a duplicate of *the deleted question*"

How can a new question be a duplicate of a deleted question?

My question (now undeleted): [How to navigate back and resume my app without hanging it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392811/black-screen-and-app-shutdown-when-trying-to-go-back-to-a-previous-class-androi)

Comment: Gain rep, and put a bounty on it.

Comment: The system prevented you from abusing it, and your complaining that you weren't allowed to abuse the system?  Really?

Comment: Related:  [What should you do if nobody answers your question? Can you repost it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265233/what-should-you-do-if-nobody-answers-your-question-can-you-repost-it)

Comment: Just think about it - if you could do what you attempted, all immoral SO users would be running scripts to continually delete and repost their questions in an attempt to keep their own stuff on top of the pile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was it an exact duplicate of the deleted question?

If so then system is quite correct in telling you that you can't post it again.

What you should be doing is editing the original question to add any more information you've discovered since the question was posted, clarifying points that you now realise are unclear etc.

Editing puts the question back on the front page of the site where it'll get more views and hopefully, if you've added enough information, an answer or two.