# Is this conflict of interest an abuse of closing privileges?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, privileges

I recently ran across the following comment

> [According to Should I flag a question as duplicate if it has received better answers?, I'm closing the other question a duplicate of this one. I think my answer on this question is better than the answers in the the other older question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992070/is-sumi-undefined-behavior-in-c#comment42523201_26992070)

This seems like a serious conflict of interest and possible abuse of duplicate closing privileges and one that is incredibly self serving. So, what is the official guidance in situations like this?

Comment: I can't see that comment - it's been deleted. So I find it very hard to tell what you're talking about here. Who did what and when and why?

Comment: I didn't say it "makes the question any less valid", I said I'm having a hard time figuring out what you're complaining about.

Comment: I guess you didn't read the question that the accused party linked to, then. Duplicate-marking does not have to go older->newer. And not everything that is related to ones own posts is "a reputation grab": that's an accusation of bad faith and I hope you can back it up with evidence.

Comment: My primary concern here is that the closer is also the highest voted answerer, thus by closing they favor themselves.

Comment: Were they right? Was their answer better? That's what we should be asking, not how much rep they'll get out of it and therefore how nasty and evil they are.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't think it was any better or worse than the existing answers on the other question, but that's just my  opinion

Comment: I think I've finally figured out which posts were dupes of what and who closed what as what and when. Performing final edit to my answer, now.

Comment: Please flag or re-arrange the close votes as needed; I'm not an expert in C++ by any means, so it's quite possible I mixed up the duplicates in trying to revert everything to its original state.

Comment: Thanks for sorting out the questions in question _[sic]_, @George

Comment: @downvoter just curious why? Is it incorrect to ask if conflicts of interest should be flagged?

Comment: @Kevin please read the answers below, the person who closed the question originally answered this question as well.

Comment: I did not vote, but I suspect the down votes might include someone who thought the use of the word "abuse" and the term "serious conflict" seemed too strong. I wouldn't down vote for that (certainly, I've seen much worse language used!) but it actually kept me from up-voting, too.

Comment: A new example: I recently closed [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19188688/827263) as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957967/linking-error-gcc-lm), which I had [previously answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8957987/827263). In my opinion the closure was appropriate, but somebody pointed out (not unreasonably) that it might be considered an abuse of power. If this is considered an abuse of power, perhaps the system shouldn't permit it. For example, it could reduce my close vote to the normal kind if I've answered the other question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Something I've learned as a moderator:

> If it's possible your action will be viewed as a conflict of interest, ask for help.

In the case of the super-close vote dupe hammer, that means flagging the post for moderator attention "Other", and explaining the situation.

Not doing so could be considered an abuse of close vote powers.

**Close Voters:**

If you see an instance where you genuinely believe the older questions have not been answered sufficiently, add your answer to those older questions. Close the newer question as a duplicate; but take **extreme care** to make sure there's not an appearance of a conflict of interest.

Closing as a duplicate entails looking at the questions in their totality:

- How many views do they have?
- How many votes do they have?
- How complete are the answers?

None of those criteria involve taking into account your answers to a question.

If you are involved in a question and you think other questions may be a duplicate, the best thing you can do is to flag the question for moderator involvement using a custom flag and explaining the situation.

That's what we do when we're involved in a post, and that's what the community expects you to do in these situations.

Again, please use your powers judiciously and without appearance of a conflict of interest.

Comment: I think you may be overstating the "conflict of interest" angle where all there is to gain is a small smattering handful of imaginary internet points.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not at all; there is also the issue of trust. If the system seems corrupt, then that hurts Stack Overflow as a whole.  Yea, they may be imaginary internet points; but that's not all they are -- they're a foundation of trust.

Comment: Right, and we're [supposed to assume good faith](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). You are apparently doing the opposite?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not at all.  I can assume a user was trying to be helpful; but I also have to weigh the impact on the community. If there's a perception that a certain action will result in a negative effect on the community; it's my duty as a moderator to work to curtail that action, no matter the intentions behind it.

Comment: Yes, but I think you missed what I was trying to say. You used the term "abuse"; how does that suggest you considered that the user "was trying to be helpful"? This manner of dupe-closing action happens all the time with no community backlash. But now, as of this single example, you're suggesting that _any_ such action would be considered "conflict of interest" and "abuse of power". That's sad to hear and really goes against the good faith requirement. You're just jumping straight to the negative angle.

Comment: *"If it's possible your action will **be viewed as** a conflict of interest, ask for help."* Emphasis mine; that's an excellent point to make. It's not just if it *is* a conflict - but if it would appear to be. Getting a non-interested party to take the action they think appropriate is always a good idea in these cases.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Yeah it would certainly avoid the whole problem :) As I said elsewhere, I do that myself. Still, I think automatically categorising someone who doesn't think it's necessary as "abusive" is a reach.

Comment: @lightness it appears that you're using a strawman argument: I never claimed a person was 'abusive', I claimed that certain actions 'could be considered an abuse of close vote powers.'

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Someone who is seen to commit "an abuse" is seen to "be abusive". I'm not sure how else you'd define the term... Sooo yes I believe you did claim that. Sorry if I misunderstood and you didn't, but I am very careful not to make strawman arguments.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This might just be a semantic thing, I think. I tend to think that someone who is "abusive" has more of a pattern of abuse, whereas one can simply happen to abuse something, but not have a 'pattern'. I think that's where George is coming from there. I can see what you mean, too; but now that the semantic thing is explained...

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Mm, perhaps...

Comment: Is the number of views really relevant? I've never considered it when choosing duplicates - I typically rank by *quality of answers* > *votes* > *date asked*.

Comment: @bergi yes; a high number of views/ time usually correlates to a better Google rank for a question, given that most of our traffic comes from Google. The dupe also allows the links to honor rel=canonical; important to maintain Google juice.

Comment: Hm, I've come across questions with high view count but few upvotes - and likely the question was not about what the googlers searched for (though the buzzwords matched). So I thought votes were more relevant.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Besides Andrew Barber's point, I think you're interpreting George Stocker's *"could be considered an abuse"* to be a euphemism for *"is an abuse"* when it isn't (to my reading) meant that way. All he's saying (I think) is that some people seeing the closure could reasonably interpret it as an abuse, and *whether or not* he personally agrees with that interpretation the fact that it's reasonably possible to see that way is a good enough reason to discourage the behaviour because perception is important.

Comment: @MarkAmery *Exactly.*

Comment: @MarkAmery /cc George Fair enough.

Comment: Do you think your viewpoint here applies to regular duplicate votes (non-hammer)?

Comment: @radiodef no, because they aren't unilateral actions.

Comment: I agree with you that we should avoid an appearance of conflict of interest but it does blunt the usefulness of the feature for sufficiently active users. Perhaps it would be more useful if the hammer converted to a regular vote to close if the voter has an answer in the duplicate nominated?

Comment: This raises some interesting questions about the gold badge hammers. Essentially, having a gold badge entails the abilities and **responsibilities** of a *moderator*, meaning that users with this power should think and behave like a moderator, even though they probably never asked for this power or the accompanying responsibility. Perhaps the hammers are a bit overkill.

Comment: Are the criteria you use above(*more vote, more views, competeness of answers*) covered in more detail in another meta post? What level of more views/votes matters, double, triple more? What if the answers are equally complete or close? For example a question I recently [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27751221/1708801) was closed as a duplicate of a questions with a lot fewer votes and half the views, the answers are close enough to complete in both to be hard to choose a winner, should it be switched around?

Answer (score 41):

It's done by me, and has been reversed by a moderator.

Here's a detailed version of what happened: I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992070/is-sumi-undefined-behavior-in-c) earlier. And it turned out to be a duplicate of [an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485088/what-does-the-operation-c-ab-mean). Later, when I got plenty of free time, I read the old question and all of its answers. I think my answer is better than any one of them. Then I searched on Meta to see what I could do on such situation, and ask a question if there's no one already. I found the question [Should I flag a question as duplicate if it has received better answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers) and read it carefully. I think it can apply to my problem. Then it's what you saw, I duplicated the old question to the new one, and left a comment explaining why I did that.

I must add that I'm not advertising my answer, I simply thought my answer is better. None of the answers of the old question explained it from the C standard point to this language-lawyer question.

The moderator has sent to me a message explaining why it could be considered an abuse of my close-vote power. I understand it and will be more careful in the future.

---

I hope people can read my answer and the old question before judging. I'm not expecting you to think my answer is better, just expecting you to believe that I'm not advertising my answer, or, as OP comments, *reputation grab*. As for the question, I trust the judgement of @Lightness Races in Orbit(as an expert in the language) that my answer isn't good enough to earn such action.

I understand the rule now,  I'm still a little sad though :(

Comment: +1: Thank you for coming here and explaining. You followed policy to the letter and, although the community ultimately disagreed that your answer was sufficiently better than the older ones to warrant the closure, you acted in good faith. Also note that not everyone thinks that this was any sort of "abuse" :)

Comment: I've removed my comment with that language as it's not fair to you, even though that would have been a long term net effect.

Comment: Copy your answer to the old question. And to avoid self plagiarism just put a link to your accepted answer in the new question.

Comment: "I simply thought my answer was better".  This isn't surprising, because you are strongly inclined to write the sort of answer you think is better, regardless of whether that's a majority opinion in the larger community.  It's really difficult to objectively evaluate your own work.

Answer (score 18):

The base case here is that either the newer question needed closing as a dupe of the older one, or vice versa. It doesn't matter which one is older, which is what the accused party was pointing out with that policy link, though the older one is a good "default" to remain open where no other deciding factor tips the scale.

The author in question took existing guidance that this decision may come down to the quality of the answers, and acted accordingly. I've done this myself on occasion, and been supported in that action.

I certainly wouldn't call it "an egregious abuse" just because one of the answers under consideration happened to be written by the guy holding the dupe-hammer. In fact, [Stack Exchange encourages us to *assume good faith*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), which you're certainly not doing here.

However, in cases where it is not necessarily clear that your own answer is massively superior to those on an older question, it would be polite to get a few people to back you up in the comments, first.

In this particular situation, I would agree that the newer answer is probably not good *enough* to warrant this and, given the wealth of additional answers on the older question, I would disagree with the action taken. Again, though, I still see no outright evidence that the individual taking that action acted in bad faith. A moderator reversed the action and now everything's fine.

Comment: There is a dupehammer involved, indeed.

Comment: With great power comes great responsibility, I'm not saying that their actions were necessarily wrong. But should they have been the one to do it, or should they have left it to others?

Comment: @Mgetz: I don't see any real reason to require people to leave it to others. It takes a lot of time to get a gold tag badge on SO: if we can't trust those users to act responsibly, who can we trust? And when they make a decision that people disagree with, we can simply undo the action. I really see no problem here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit a conflict of interest is always viewed in bad faith. There is simply no other way to view it.

Comment: @Mgetz: You could simply view it in _good_ faith instead, by stopping assuming that every action someone takes that may end up resulting in some gain for them was taken in pursuit of that gain. By assuming that, and fighting against the action due to it, you may inadvertently make the _wrong_ decision. Basically, so what if they get more rep out of it if their action was the right one?

Comment: I agree with Mgetz, in just about any profession's code of ethics, you need to avoid not only wrongdoing, but the appearance of wrongdoing. Judges, lawyers, accountants, arbitrators, anyone, they avoid acting in any issue in which they have any kind of personal stake, precisely to avoid any such appearance. Assuming good or bad faith just doesn't really come into it, because when you avoid those appearances, you don't need to assume anything. It's a fundamental ethical principle, really.

Comment: _I still see no outright evidence that the individual taking that action acted in bad faith:_ I would even say that the individual acted in good faith. Otherwise he wouldn't have left a comment where here made transparent to everybody what he did, why he did it, and how he is involved in the affected posts.

Comment: Acting in good faith is not enough.  One is biased toward one's own answer, in part because one writes the sort of answer one thinks is good.

Comment: @BenVoigt: So is it also "an abuse" and assumed "bad faith" to accept your own answer to your question over someone else's? Or to downvote all other answers on someone else's question when you genuinely think they're all wrong except yours? No, of course not... We _all_ vote with our natural biases and that's why it's a voting system in the first place. Arguably the same does not quite apply to wielding a dupe-hammer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I know of other Q&A systems where moderators indeed can accept their own answer to arbitrary questions.  The outcome is quite bad.  It's possible to abuse good answers on your own question by accepting an inferior answer; it makes very little difference who wrote that inferior answer.  But the right to evaluate answers and assign the green checkmark has always belonged to the one asking the question.  There's no comparison between what happened here, and self-answering your own question.

Comment: The bias towards one's own answer is not the problem; it's the effect of said bias on unilateral action.