# Dupe-hammer abuse

Tags: discussion, support, dupehammer

To be clear, I've already read [Is this conflict of interest an abuse of closing privileges?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277126/is-this-conflict-of-interest-an-abuse-of-closing-privileges/277129#277129)

To get into the meat of the question, without naming any specific parties, I have to ask/wonder if there is a way of preventing dupe-hammer abuse, such as a way to remove the privilege for a set amount of time or something.

I'm also wondering if, severity wise, a single flag would suffice; I feel in this specific case, the flag is warranted, but if the flag will be meaningless, I don't want to both waste my time, and the time of the moderator looking at it.

In the case that prompted this question, there is no further action to be taken on the question where the misuse has occurred; it was already taken.  Thus there is no point in linking it.

I guess to get right down to it, I'm wondering of the proper course of action here.

Comment: what abuse are you trying to stop?  A user can only vote to close and vote to reopen once per question

Comment: @NathanOliver The kind of abuse that results from a specific user being targeted.

Comment: So one user going around and dupe close voting another users questions?

Comment: @NathanOliver As far as I am aware, it only happened once, though it happened nonetheless.  While I am not a fan of the user that was targeted, I still believe it was an abuse of the tool.

Comment: If it happened once, how can it be abuse?

Comment: It does just take a single user to get a bunch of people to over-react.  That's what you are doing right now, you'll need to stop that.  This clown isn't worth it.

Comment: If you see something like this mod flag and walk away.  We don't need extra controls.

Comment: @xPeke To defend my reasoning here, is it not abuse when one user targets another, for the sole purpose of getting on that user's nerves, when the question did not warrant the action?

Comment: How can you be sure about the whole *targeting* issue, do you have **evidence** to back up/support your statement? @Daedalus

Comment: @xPeke I do, two bits of it that are quite damning.  However, others are already aware of the case I speak of, the question is just really what to do; flag or ignore.  I don't think ignore is the right action, but I'm still unsure, hence this meta question.

Comment: Show them to a mod then.... @Daedalus otherwise I will just assume you're making assumptions, which happens quite often on this site...

Comment: @Daedalus you should flag those two bits for moderator attention and clearly describe what you perceive the problem to be. You get 500 chars to make your case.

Comment: ^----- agree @TinyGiant

Comment: Closing and reopening quarrels happen all the time.  However, the question here should be if there is a *persistent pattern*. Single incidents don't add up to a picture, and aren't worth a mod flag. Targetting specific users would be.

Comment: @Daedalus You've been on the network for 4 years and 4 months, and you still don't know what course of action to take? I believe you're pretty knowledgeable of how SO works

Comment: @TinyGiant What you said prior is accurate.

Comment: @xPeke I have, yes, and aside from a single year I've been active for most of it.   Anyway, to the point, I didn't think there was harm in being sure of an action.

Comment: @HansPassant At this point, you're right; on top of what had already happened, it would indeed be a waste of time.

Comment: In the end you should do what you think it's right, SO gives you the liberty to do so. So your flag may or may not be approved, but you did your part and that should be the end of it. No need for these type of questions. @Daedalus

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you feel that anyone is abusing *any* site feature (close/reopen votes included), the correct course of action is to flag for mod attention and let them handle the situation.

Be specific.  Explain what you think is wrong, why you think it is wrong, and potentially what you think needs to be done to rectify the situation.

Comment: Just one question; would your answer change if you knew(assuming you don't already) the prompting question?

Comment: @Daedalus I'm reasonably confident that I'm familiar with the case that prompted this.  I'm also completely confident that if I'm guessing wrong, the correct course of action is still to flag the post and let a mod sort it out.

Comment: Assuming I'm correct on your own assumption, your confidence isn't misplaced.