# Why exactly is this question closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, closed-questions, reopen-closed

This JavaScript question ([Does JavaScript have "Short-circuit" evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554578/does-javascript-have-short-circuit-evaluation)) was closed as a duplicate, with the following questions as dupe-targets:

- [*Using &&'s short-circuiting as an if statement?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049006/using-s-short-circuiting-as-an-if-statement#)
- *[Does javascript use optimization in boolean expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858787/does-javascript-use-optimization-in-boolean-expressions)*

Now I found the answers there to be somewhat lacking in terms of depth and have written an extensive and detailed answer regarding [short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/short-circuiting) in [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) including an extensive definition and look 'under the hood', plus some common gotchas. Obviously, purely subjectively speaking, I think an answer of good quality which would be a good contribution.

Issue is, the questions, which the original question is considered a duplicate to are in the first case specifically asking only about `&&` operator  and in the second case I would argue the question is much broader and of much lesser quality.

Further reasoning would be the very definition of the question, which reflects on the question popularity. The closed question **has a clear title, defining the subject matter the question is about**, meanwhile the two 'duplicates' are only tackling a specific issue.

Further supported by the views, where the closed question has *37k* views, meanwhile the two duplicates have only *8k* and *1k* views.

Now AFAIK, the goal of Stack Overflow is to provide the best answers to the best possible questions.

- My answer **is specifically answering** the question which is closed and treated as duplicate (which it isn't)
- **The "closed" question is exponentially more popular than the two questions** that are being linked to (and hence won't be viewed by as many people) and for a good reason (check point 3)
- **The question is not even really a duplicate.** The subject matter is similar, but the question is tackling [short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/short-circuiting) as in whole, meanwhile the two other questions are just specifically asking about one of the concepts in the subject matter.

Given this reasoning, could the question be reopened please *(also would be nice if my 4 hours of effort didn't go to waste)*

Comment: The question was closed almost 7 years ago. Why would you _"waste"_ hours writing an answer for a closed question?

Comment: @yivi Because I feel like the subject matter is insufficiently explained and requires the user to seek other resources. I don't see, why contributing with an in-depth quality answer to a question, just because it's old should be viewed as something negative.

Comment: The issue is not that is old, is that it is **closed**. Wouldn't it make sense to see _first_ to reopen it and then if it is spend the 4 hours writing whatever answer you want to write?

Comment: I don't think a yes or no question with a yes or no answer needs any further explanation than the answer provided.

Comment: No not really. I don't care too much about "karma", so I would contribute it to one of the other questions regardless. But if I would have the option to, I'd much rather post the answer to a fitting question.

Comment: If I were you, I'd spend my time writing answers to questions currently open, and unlikely to get closed. Less chance of "wasted effort" that way.

Comment: You could just ask a different question and answer it yourself. Just make sure it is different from existing questions, and link to similar questions, indicating how your question differs. Also ensure it meets the quality standards described in [ask] and the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Why would I ask a new question, when i'd be asking the exactly same question as the one which is locked?

Comment: No question was [locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post). "Locked" and "closed" have different meanings on the site.

Comment: *'closed'* then,  but my point stays the same

Comment: First and foremost, your answer should directly answer the question. It shouldn't require the user to read 1-2 paragraphs and several examples and then based on the result infer that the answer is "yes".

Comment: I do agree to you. The given answers on all three questions are ... well ... not really extensive. I think this should be restructured somehow, maybe reversing the dupes? (So that the other ones point at the most viewed one? Then adding some good answers there?)

Comment: In my opinion, your answer would be better on an entirely different question. On that asks what short circuiting is in general. No such question appears to exist on stackoverflow.

Comment: @kevin I'm not sure. A lot of people saw that thread, probably because they searched for "short circuiting js" because they've heard the term somewhere. Getting a simple "Yes, JS has short-circuiting" might help people coming from another language that already know what they are looking for. I think all those others could really benefit from a good explanation.

Comment: @yivi oh well, most questions / answers are seen by ... the one asking. The ones we are talking about now are seen by thousands of people, they really have an impact. We are still not writing "yet another answer on a Q & A site" but we are rather curators of a knowledge database.

Comment: @JonasWilms very nicely worded. You actually managed to get my point accross in two comments than I did in my entire question

Comment: I raised a bounty on the now reopened question, may the best answer win :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wether or not you wrote an answer that you found helpful is not a judgement for the duplicates.

*However* it is our duty to curate this knowledgebase, and obviously a lot of people were looking for "short circuiting in JS", some of them may know the term from another language already, for them the accepted answer ("Yes") will already be helpful. For all those others, that may not know short-circuiting yet, the question is not useful at all. The duplicates also do not provide any help.

KevinB reopened the main question and reversed the duplicate chain. I just created a bounty on the question.

Through that we hopefully create a good canonical for questions about short-circuiting, at a place were a lot of people can benefit from it.

Answer (score 9):

It is closed because we already have questions that answer the same issue already on the site.

The question is not deleted as it is good signpost duplicate (and I think it is perfectly fine to be that way).

Your possible options

- provide better answer on existing duplicate, possibly making question a bit more general
- find better duplicate and edit duplicates list (possibly closing linked once as duplicate of the same one too) - i.e. [JavaScript OR (||) variable assignment explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation) has very good explanations.
- if you can't find better duplicate suggest to make that question "canonical" and work on reversing the links
- post new canonical Q&A and close all linked post as duplicate of new one. (I don't think this is a good option as question itself is of very low "research shown" score)

Comment: Given that, I find this rather to be an issue with how the duplicate hierarchy is organized then. If my answer is regarding both the `&&` and `||` operator, then your answer would imply, I should post the same answer twice, separately in both questions - *which is silly if you ask me*

Comment: I mean, one of the two questions wouldn't be answered by your answer at all... so the decision as to which to apply your answer to should be easy. Just make sure you tailor it to the question.

Comment: @KevinB, that's why the top upvoted and accepted answer is a link-only answer which redirects you to short-circuit evaluation, the very thing I want to answer? (talking about the linked question in Alexei's answer now)

Comment: @Rawrplus Vote to reopen if it if you want it reopened. That's how this place works. then you'll just have to wait for 4 people to agree with you.

Comment: I was kind of hoping this question would act as a re-opening vote, but I guess those are technically two different things. I mean don't get me wrong, I get your explanation, it's just I find it commical that in **both the `&&` and the `||` question, the go-to answer is a refferal to short-circuit evaluation**, yet the topic about short-circuit evaluation **is closed**

Comment: @kevin or just one goldbadger (maybe me, I'm still waiting for some feedback)

Comment: i don't think it really *needs* to be closed, but i'd hate to lose the association to the other two more specific questions. I'd hope reopening would be followed by linking the other two to it. Even after that however, i'm still of the opinion that the potentional answer provided (in the deleted answer) here is quite poor, and wholly unnecessary. The explanation from the tag wiki is far more concise.

Comment: @KevinB the discussion here is not regarding the quality of the answer, but whether the question should be re-opened

Comment: As to the link, I wholeheartedly agree, that some reference to the other two questions would be welcome. My point here is not being, that these other two are not relevant, but that if anything, the duplicacy should be other way around, with both of them being duplicates of the short-circuit evaluation

Comment: The other two questions are already linked it seems, so i cast a vote

Answer (score 0):

Let me begin by noting I sympathise when it comes to suboptimal duplicate targets. A particularly tricky scenario is when the duplicate target is an old, popular question with a grab bag of answers of mixed quality, while the question closed against it is better formulated and has a high quality, very precise answer. In such cases, the temptation is strong to go ahead and [reverse the duplicate closure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251938/2751851), though I haven't been bold enough to actually do that yet, partly because [there has been pushback against such actions in the past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277126/2751851). At any rate, that could be an interesting topic for a Meta discussion one of these days.

The specific case you have brought here, however, is not simply a matter of choosing the best duplicate target, as you also planned to post [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56057305/2751851) to your pick of duplicate target. I don't feel that was the best course of action. That question, as asked, is a very straightforward one ("I would like to know if JavaScript has "short-circuit" evaluation like && Operator in C#"), to which [a similarly straightforward answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12554597/2751851) appears entirely appropriate. An answer like yours, which goes over the details of how short-circuiting works, would be a better fit for a question that actually required answers that account for such details. In fact, [searching for questions tagged [javascript] and [short-circuiting]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript%2bshort-circuiting?tab=Votes) quickly led me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19300773/2751851), which, less than ideal title aside, is essentially about short-circuiting minutiae, and has an answer which covers similar ground to yours.

All in all, I believe you should consider following one of the suggestions in [Alexei Levenkov's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384763/2751851).