# Should I ask a question I know the answer to, if I think it will be useful to others?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, canonical

In answering questions, sometimes the new users don't know how to do simple debugging. I was thinking of creating a resource which would provide information on how to do that here on Stack Overflow.

I was thinking I would ask a question such as "How do I debug my Java code?" and answer it myself. Plus, if another person gives a better answer, I could accept theirs instead.

I did find a similar question [How can I debug my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745714/how-can-i-debug-my-code)

However, it is tagged with [netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netbeans) - and I would like to provide multiple IDE examples.

I suppose really my questions are the following:

1. In general, should I ask a question I know the answer too if I think it will be useful to others? Is there a more useful way to post something like this, here on Stack Overflow?
2. In this case, should I ask the question? Or, should I add it to the existing question even though all of it doesn't apply to that question?

---

*The question that this question is marked a duplicate of is asking about a user who is seeking additional answers to the one he already has.*

*If it **is** to be considered a duplicate, I think my question is more valuable to the site since it has better quality and more direct answers. According to [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252017/2974766) the other question should be closed instead, in my opinion.*

Comment: Then it's answered in any of the other linked questions. This has come up before. See [meta-tag:self-answer] as well as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, of course you can; from the help center:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

And the most famous example of this:

[What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Just make sure both the question *and* answer are up to the quality standards of SO and you'll be fine. "How do I debug my code in < insert IDE >" could easily make a good canonical question (though it smells a bit broad).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this is similar to your last suggestion.

Comment: @codeMagic Yeah; I see that. Yes; the link is a good example of a "debugging" canonical question.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific instance, "How do I debug my Java code?" and "I would like to provide multiple IDE examples" suggest that such a question would likely be closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with a self-answer, however, canonical/FAQ questions such as these:

- [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)
- [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)
- [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

...have a narrow, specific scope to their domain/tool. To quote [Andrew Medico](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277453/3920237):

> In this specific instance, "How do I debug my Java code?" and "I would
>   like to provide multiple IDE examples" suggest that such a question
>   would likely be closed as "too broad".

StackOverflow is meant to be a repository of detailed answers to *specific* questions and not be [customer support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) for "[a user's] favorite company". If there is a common issue related to debugging and related to [netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netbeans) that you feel can make a good canonical question, then by all means, post it. However, I wouldn't recommend adding a new answer to the question you linked as it seems to be asking "How do I debug in Netbeans?" and that is what the documentation is for.