# Asking the same question on Stack Overflow and other online forums?

Tags: discussion, answers, self-answer, views

This is specifically for less popular tags like Jdbc , PL/SQL , Weblogic , WLST etc.

I have asked questions related to the above tags and have noticed that the post receives very few and sometimes no responses. They are also not very highly viewed either. So the post really isn't getting much attention here.

Which is why I often end up posting the same question on other sites like Oracle Forum. Eventually the question does get answered either on Stack Overflow or Oracle forums.

Say if the post is fully answered on the other forum, would it then be fair to post the same answer (by answering my own post) on Stack Overflow (Providing a link or an acknowledgement to the original responder).

The only reason one would want to do this is for the benefit of those in this forum who may run into the same issues. Are there any guidelines for such cases/practices?

Comment: Yes, avoid link-only answers(copy the relevant text into your answer so that it can stand alone if link breaks in future) and use proper acknowledgement. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277450/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to-if-i-think-it-will-be-useful-to-ot

Comment: Make sure that the other site's content license allows you to reproduce its content somewhere else.  StackOverflow allows this with attribution, but other sites may not.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is entirely fair. There is nothing that prevents you from asking the same question on another site. But if you do, please be so kind to not abandon your post on either site when you get the answer.

As you say, if you post an answer on SO/SE that you got somewhere else, then do provide the proper attribution. And make sure to not just link to it.

Comment: I would add, ["Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251475/839601)

Comment: Yeah, a good example is the qt tag where desperate newbies ask question on SO as well as the Qt forum.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's good practice

but let other too know the answer for the questions

Also provide an acknowledgement