# Why do duplicate questions sometimes have high ratings?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I have seen several duplicate questions which have high ratings. Why is this? For example this question: [Difference between uint32 and uint32_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362084/difference-between-uint32-and-uint32-t). It was marked a duplicate **the day it was posted** (in fact an hour after), and yet has higher ratings and views than the question it was a duplicate of.

Even though it was marked a duplicate so soon after its posting, it still gained much more attention than I think it should have. That is not the only example of this scenario. When I find more I'll post them here (I've seen many). Is there something we are doing wrong?

Comment: Networking in a Q&A system is an amazing thing. There are many not so obvious dupes, still providing value to many researchers.

Comment: [There are 1,734 duplicate questions with a score greater than or equal to 27 (the current score of the post you linked to)](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate%3Ayes+score%3A27..). People upvote them because there is nothing wrong with a duplicate question, the duplicate closing process is just to link posts together and focus any future answers in one place.

Comment: Is there something wrong with a duplicate having a decent score? The way your post reads, there is- But if the duplicate is a good, well-written and otherwise on-topic question, what's wrong with people upvoting it? Duplicates aren't necessarily _bad_ things- Just signposts to point to other questions, preferably with all the answers on the other question. (Sometimes that doesn't happen- Such is life.)

Comment: It has *five* times the number of views.  The more succinct question title gives it better Google juice.

Comment: in theory it is desirable for [duplicate direction](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251938/839601) to favor questions with better answers. In practice, people very rarely worry about this, especially if this involves "inversion" of existing and established duplicate

Comment: _Is there something we are doing wrong?_ - The only thing that might be going wrong is that the original or dupe target question has a title that's making it hard for people to find in the first place, hence the duplicates.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Why is this?

It might be that more people search for specifically the `uint32` problem than "different integer types".

While [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786113/difference-between-different-integer-types) "shows research effort, is useful and clear", the duplicate is short, to the point, and an actual problem that many might enter verbatim into Google.

As @HansPassant said in a comment:

> It has five times the number of views. The **more succinct question
>   title** gives it better Google juice.

Concerning your question:

> Is there something we are doing wrong?

[Kaizen (改善)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaizen) (continuous improvement) always applies. Here, merging might be sensible.

Comment: It is the example why duplicate questions are kept around at all (to be a sign post)

Comment: In addition a duplicate question, if succinctly formulated, may elicit a better answer,or a more up-to-date answer.  There is no guarantee that an accepted answer is the best answer, or will always remain the best answer.

Comment: @TomD: Yes. And if that happens, we can flag for a mod to merge the questions.

Answer (score 12):

> Why do duplicate questions sometimes have high ratings?

It's not ideal, but duplicate questions are often easily understood and answered.  Because of this, it's easier for people to judge the usefulness of the post and vote.  A lot of times the duplicate is not nearly as obvious as the answer.  So by the time people realize it's a duplicate, it has already been active enough to get tons of views and votes.

> Is there something we are doing wrong?

That's an ongoing debate that I don't want to answer.

Comment: If you think you're doing nothing wrong, that's what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 11):

An alternative explanation is that at least some of the duplicates in fact aren't. I've seen some gold-badge-based insta-dupe-closes for questions that were related to, but by far not identical to their misidentified dupes. This is something we as a community are doing wrong, which might reflect in views and votes aswell, since reversing these sudo-closes is not possible for most users.

Comment: yes the "exact duplicate" term is interpreted broadly here ;-) More seriously, Jeff Atwood [says it nicely](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/): "**cultivating and supporting a moderate amount of natural duplication actively helps the community**"

Comment: [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo)-closes != pseudo-closes.  man uptime.

Comment: Oh, I thought hiergiltdiestfu really does mean "sudo", since they're closes executed using elevated privileges.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I indeed meant sudo, not pseudo. :)

Answer (score 2):

Other possible answer : **with time, answers change**

While this is not the reason for this particular question, I have seen this for other questions : when a post is from 2009, its accepted and most voted answer is not always the best one in 2015

Answer (score 2):

A new question will be on the front page of a larger fraction of the current active users of the site than an old question. A typical question gets a flood of votes from the currently active users when it is new, because it appears on their front page, and then has a steady trickle of votes from people searching for questions and answers. The site has grown very quickly. Therefore the flood of initial votes is much larger for a question posted today than for even three years ago. So a new question that is actually worse quality than a similar but better old question can gain more votes than the old question.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** the issue with this specific pair of questions, but i have found that on occasions questions do get closed as duplicates because some people believe that it is answered in a more broad question; but the questioner cannot find the solution there.

Look at my question [What is the format for --date parameter of git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742345/what-is-the-format-for-date-parameter-of-git-commit) it was marked by one commenter as a potential duplicate of [How can one change the timestamp of an old commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git) (note: my question wasn't closed at this time, but i think it was just a fluke). And if one concentrates on the titles of the questions, then yes, mine could be considered to be a rehashing of the old one. But there are no answers there that deal with the format of the date, they all just assume that everybody should know what it is. If we start merging everything, then we end up with a questions like "What are different ways to commit the source code?" and everything else getting redirected there.

Answer (score 1):

I think what McMastery is getting at is the undesirability of duplicates.  We would rather people researched and found the original, rather than create a duplicate of the same question.  But sometimes the duplicate does add value, as in this case, making the topic easier to find.  Then linking the duplicate to the original connects them and provides the benefit with some measure of unity.  That being the case, it should be ok for that duplicate to get more upvotes and views - recognition of the added value.  But I imagine sometimes the duplicate provides no added value and still gets more upvotes.  I just don't see how that can be avoided without a greater loss of missing out on the benefit those duplicates sometimes provide.

Answer (score -3):

Duplicates often represent alternative approaches to framing a problem. Cross-reference answers improve your chances of finding information, question suppression does not. I suspect this is what Jeff Atwood was talking about, although I can't be certain.

This issue drives me wild to the point where every now and then I seriously think about setting up an alternative to stack overflow before remembering how big a project that would be and how expensive to host if successful.

Here's my thesis in a nutshell:

> Free-text search beats curation as conclusively shown by yahoo
>   versus google. Therefore curation is a waste of time and all these 
>   rules and all the effort put into policing them have no value, or 
>   even negative value when they inhibit other purposes.

I've tried expounding this view several times, with various responses that boil down to ignoring the above and favouring rules over people.

I have asked myself why this is so, and I think the root problem is that the only thing worse than a professional bureaucrat is a volunteer bureaucrat.