# Which one should I flag if a duplicate has worse question and better answer (I think) at the same time?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

I know flagging duplicates should follow guidelines [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938) that choosing one having better questions or answers, but how about if a duplicate is a bad question but I think it has a better answer?

I'm troubling in choosing which one should flag in the following questions:

[the new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362654)

[the old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662189)

I think the old one is a better question (the sentence is clearer to understand, and also has higher score), but I also think the new one contains a better answer (I think, even currently it has lower score than best answer of another one). Which question should be closed as duplicate in this case?

Comment: Why do you consider the answer on the new one better than the older one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the newer one should be closed as a dupe of the older one in this case.

If you really feel that the answer is super fantastic (I'm not sure it is), you might suggest to its author that they should go and expand a little on their answer, but post it on the other question.

The other thing to consider is: why not edit the questions?