# When unsure which of 2 questions should be marked as a duplicate of the other, is it acceptable to flag (or vote to close) both?

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, duplicate-questions, moderators

Is it a good idea to cross-flag (or cross-close-vote) duplicate questions?

2 advantages of doing that:

1. You have double the attention in the Close Votes queue. Your request is more likely to be handled and less likely to get aged away.
2. Sometimes, 2 duplicate questions go unnoticed for a long time and have both gotten high-quality answers. It's unclear in these cases which should be marked as a duplicate of which. Close Vote reviewers are fast and will probably click "yes" to your flag (or close vote) if they see that the questions are similar, without thoroughly inspecting the situation. By flagging both questions, the reviewers will see both sides of the story.

I have read [Should I flag a question as duplicate if it has received better answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers), but it didn't answer my question because **this question is about cross-flagging,** or flagging both questions when one cannot decide which one should be the duplicate.

Comment: @JoshCaswell This question is not a duplicate of Should I flag a question as duplicate if it has received better answers?. This question is about cross-flagging, or flagging both questions when one cannot decide which one should be the duplicate.

Comment: Flag whichever question you think is worse (or has worse answers) as a duplicate whichever you think is better (or has better answers). Which is clearer/easier to search for? If you really can't decide... Maybe don't flag? Ask in an appropriate chat room if you'd like. I don't see a point to "cross-flagging" as you're suggesting, as it's just going to put both posts into review and only one needs to be. (Usually, at least.)

Comment: @narawagames: "*This question is about cross-flagging, or flagging both questions when one cannot decide which one should be the duplicate.*" Which is based on you not knowing which one to flag. If you answer the question of which to flag, then you won't want to cross flag, so it won't come up.

Comment: If you're unable to determine which is the better question (or with better answers), just don't flag.  There's enough of a review backlog on the Close queue that it really won't matter, and cross-posting will just add more review/moderator work than necessary.

Comment: The answer to "should I 'cross-flag'" is just "No, \[do the thing that we already figured out you should do\](url-of-meta-post-about-what-you-should-do)."

Comment: *"so when the moderators receive the flags, they'll decide which one should be the duplicate?"*. Flags go into a review queue and gets handled one at a time. Reviewers will not see both at the same time so even if both flags are handled by the same person they would already have made a judgement about the first before even seeing the second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is never *useful* for you to mark both as a duplicate of the other. Moderators will be able to see the source and destination just fine from a single flag.

> But what should one do if there're 2 questions that ask basically the same thing, but the one posted later is higher-quality than the one posted first?

That's irrelevant. Or at least, it's not important.

If the later question has no answers, then you should mark it as a duplicate of the other. Why? To stop people from adding duplicate answers and therefore scattering content.

If the later question does have answers, then it doesn't really matter which is the source and which is the destination anymore. So long as you don't make a cycle of duplication, do whatever you feel makes things clearer for people reading it.