# Resolving duplicate: older question vs more specific for NSException in Swift questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

There are 4 (probably more) similar questions about catching NSException in Swift:

1. [Catching NSException in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32758811/3050403)
   Asked: Sep 24, 2015
   Upvotes: 58
   Answers: 4
2. [Catch Objective-C exception in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35119531/3050403)
   Asked: Jan 31, 2016
   Upvotes: 7
   Answers: 3
3. [Swift Catch Runtime Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42973687/3050403)
   Asked: Mar 23, 2017
   Upvotes: 2
   Answers: 1
4. [Catch an exception for invalid user input in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24710424/3050403)
   Asked: Jul 14, 2014
   Upvotes: 10
   Answers: 3

*Actually, there are only one unique answer for this question.*

Now I'm trying to decide, which question of this 4 shouldn't be marked as a duplicate. 2 and 3 are obviously duplicates, because they were asked later and question 2 even have an answer which is a link to question 1.

The problem is to decide between 1 and 4. Question 4 is older, but 1 is more popular and has more answer variants. The topic of 4 is specified like "catching invalid user input" but actually it's all about catching Objective-C exceptions in Swift. The 1st question has clear title.

So, how should I resolve this duplicate disambiguation? Which question is original?

My opinion is that in equal conditions the newest question should be closed as a duplicate, because it's the asker's duty to search for similar questions before creating a new one. By closing the question we punish the inattentive user.

Comment: "*2 and 3 are obviously duplicates, because they were asked later*" There's no reason you can't have a question be a duplicate of a newer question. Otherwise your decision is made: they're all duplicates of the earliest.

Comment: @WaiHaLee, then what should be the reason on your opinion? Is there any strict rules regarding duplicates on SO?

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333141/1364007) might be helpful, but I don't have enough experience in those questions to suggest something.

Comment: @WaiHaLee, you are not sure *but* still posting :) I strongly disagree with you. I added a postscriptum to the question explaining why.

Comment: Suppose somebody *doesn't*  do their due diligence and posts a duplicate question. The duplicate's answer is far better than on the original question. What would be done then? I disagree with you that closure is a punishment, though; duplicate questions have a purpose too: they act as a signpost for others.

Comment: Dupe-closing is not supposed to be punitive. It's only meant to be helpful for both the asker and future visitors. So you shouldn't take "punishment" into consideration for anything related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there wasn't rules or best practices, that why I decided to *create a precedent*.

And **the question that should be considered original is the question with the more specific title.**

There was the discussion about *punishment*, and I agree that duplicate-closing doesn't punish the author, because the question doesn't loose it's votes and the ability to upvote remains. The more important thing, which was mentioned there, is the **quality of answers**. The question with better title draws 6.75 times more attention (18552 views vs 2747) and, thus accumulates more answers. That means that the chance to find better answers is higher. Also, it's easier to the user to find the answer through the search, when the question has obvious name.

It's quite clear in this particular case, because the newer but better asked question has 6 times more upvotes and more answers. But in general, all else being equal, **I would mark the old question as a duplicate, when the newer is titled in more descriptive and definite way.**