# Deletion of duplicate question by OP because they thought that it had no value?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I know that [one should flag an old question as a duplicate of a new one if it has better answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers), but this is for a similar but bit different scenario (I think/hope). And I don't really know what to do.

Someone asked a question several months ago, and it got resolved in the comments (it was a bug in the implementation used). A few days ago, someone else asked another question that was also caused by the same bug, and it got an actual answer that was accepted with several upvotes.

Knowing that, and following the guidance of the question linked above, I closed the older original question as a duplicate of the newer one, because the old one didn't have any answers (comments don't count as answers, right?).

I still mentioned in the comments of the original that I did so because of the reasons stated above, and the OP subsequently mentioned to me that they found it unfair that I marked the older one as a duplicate. While I understand that feeling, I thought that it was better if people would get linked to the question with an answer, and not to one without one. I explained that, but then I had to go to class. Now that I'm done, I see that they deleted the question, stating that they wanted to provide a higher quality answer than the other one and thought that it (and I quote) "*became of no value (even historical), due to "marked as duplicate". It is shame to have such a questions.*". OP then subsequently delete the question.

I feel like I did the right thing, but I think it is a shame that OP deleted their question just because it was a duplicate. Now I even think that I should have reopened it (if I didn't have a class) just so that the OP could have provided a higher quality answer.

What should I do?

Comment: Seems like you did the right thing. If the OP of the closed question wanted to provide a better answer, he could still do so on the new question. No point in re-opening a dupe with only the __promise__ of a better answer. A answer that may well be inferior.

Comment: It’s really unfortunate that so many interpret a question closure as a “punishment” or sometimes even (personal) attack. But most of the times it’s just a user trying to clean up SO for the good of the community.

Comment: I don't know exactly what privileges you have, but if you can comment on deleted questions, you can comment asking OP to undelete their questions because duplicates shouldn't be deleted. If you can't comment on deleted posts but you can vote to undelete questions, you could also vote to undelete the question and add a link here so that others also can vote to undelete it, and once it gets undeleted add a comment explaining to OP why duplicates shouldn't be deleted. If you can't do any of these, you might want to flag so that a moderator does it (but I don't know if your flag will be declined).

Comment: A question without answer cannot be the target of a duplicate... Just by knowing that, you made the right choice. The user can be informed that you did it for the sake of cleaning the community, and that if he had the same intention as you, remind them to tell someone who commented a good answer to give a real answer, or if they do not, OP can do it themselves. This at least closes the question with a well marked answer and everyone benefits. Closing the question was just a bad call from OP who should be informed that you just tried to help.

Comment: `I feel like I did the right thing, but I think it is a shame that OP deleted their question just because it was a duplicate.` Was it actually a useful signpost to the question that it was a duplicate of, because if not, then it's not a shame at all, as it wasn't adding value.

Comment: Only moderators can comment on deleted posts, @Donald. So yes, you could vote to undelete and/or flag the post for moderator attention. But if you're going to flag, you're going to need to provide a good reason for us to override the decision of the person who originally posted the content.

Comment: @poke how do you expect people to react when you basically tell them their question isn't worthy of being on this site? Sometimes we forget that those aren't robots asking the questions, they're human beings with feelings. I think we err too much on the side of keeping a tidy site, there's room for alternate versions of a question especially if they're well asked.

Comment: @MarkRansom - the flip side is "how do you expect people to react when someone is throwing trash on the floor and have an entitlement attitude that they should be able to throw trash on the floor because they think telling them not to is "rude" or "hurts their feelings". Yeah, no.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson of course there are people who post trash, but I didn't think that was what we were discussing. Without a link to the question we can't know.

Comment: @MarkRansom *“their question isn't worthy of being on this site”* – That’s exactly not what a close vote says. That’s the message of a deletion, sure, but not a closure.

Comment: @poke but that's what it *feels* like when you're on the receiving end. That was my point.

Comment: @MarkRansom - it is ridiculous to expect random people to be responsible for what **anonymous others feel** about them clicking on something on what is ultimately a completely unimportant/irrelevant to anything website.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson this whole topic was generated because of *an emotional response* to a question closing. The discussion is incomplete without acknowledging that.

Comment: @MarkRansom And that’s exactly what I was referring to in my initial comment…

Comment: @MarkRansom - that is that persons problem not the communitie's. I am so tired of this crap about how *mean* the *"community"* is. When the same *community* is providing for free what most companies are paying over $100 a hour for on average. The discussion is not complete without acknowledging that this is a **personal problem** that is contrived by the person that has the hubris to complain about not getting what they think they are entitled to for some reason and **not a community problem** in any way, shape or form. You can keep apologising for their selfishness all you want.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A question without any answers that correctly answer the question should not be used as a canonical duplicate candidate.

So if you find an old question that has not been properly answered, but there are newer questions with answer(s) that do answer the question, it is perfectly fine and appropriate to close the old one as a duplicate of the new one.

The *only* concern when closing as duplicate is the ***quality*** of the question and answers(s). The best one should be preserved, post age is irrelevant. But of course they must be duplicates, asking about the very same problem.

We don't really care about who was the "pioneer" who first asked that question on SO. In fact, older questions are more likely to have crappier answers, since the quality standards of SO upon launch were lax.

The number of votes might be somewhat relevant as a rough indicator of the post quality. (As a special case, you have to be careful if there are two duplicate questions which both have very good answers that don't completely overlap.)

If everything happened as you described, you did the right thing. What the OP should have done is to see if there was a way for them to improve the question (and make post a better answer), which would merit re-opening.

There will always be others with close/re-open previligies, so if you would at some point make a bad judgement call, other user moderators will be there to correct it - this system actually works quite well. For special, tricky cases, you can always ask for live advise in the [SO close-vote review chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

Comment: `/should not be/can not be/g` can not mark an non-upvoted question as a duplicate target much less one with no answers to begin with.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson There might be upvoted/accepted answers that are incorrect or just mediocre. Which is why some domain knowledge is needed to determine if something is a suitable duplicate or not.