# What to do if the duplicate and the original question are inverted

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163092/setting-default-values-conditional-assignment) question was closed as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209982/php-equivalent-of-a-ruby-assignment-idiom) one but the first one is

1. Older
2. Better written
3. Have 20 times more views

Sometimes newer question are clearly better and than older question can become dups and eventually become merged but this is not the case.

So the second one is a duplicate, non the first one.
I tried to mark the second one as the duplicate of the first but I got an error:

> This closure would result in the 'duplicate of' navigation only leading in a circle.

I saw questions with wrong dupe direction many times and I thing that this should be not a blocking error but a warning so someone can send a flag for "dupe inversion" or like so...
What I should do?

Comment: In theory you could ask in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to do a re-open / re-close ritual (worst-case that needs 5 re-open and close voters) but I would rather see that users with a dupe hammer in either PHP or Ruby do the honors. Or flag and hope that a mod is willing to risk getting it wrong.

Comment: @rlemon This isn't a dupe of that; this question is asking how to proceed when a question has already been closed as a dupe of a worse one. That question is asking which of two questions ought to be closed as a dupe of the other.

Comment: @TylerH Right, but the answer on that question matches this one. Go with the better one. If you think that it's the wrong way around, fix it either by voting or flagging. Unless you have something to add on that?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha The answer does not address this problem at all; you can't flag or close a question as a duplicate of one closed as a duplicate of it, you get the circular closure error.

Comment: Sure, I'll accept that line of reasoning. Good luck.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha In the interest of good faith I also pinged gnat under that asking if I could add something which addresses this issue to that answer, because a more holistic canonical is always a good thing.

Comment: Even if it's not an acceptable duplicate, it's certainly relevant - is there a reason that all three comments linking to it needed to be deleted? For what it's worth, the proposed dupe was [Should I flag a question as duplicate if it has received better answers?
](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers), and the accepted answer **does** mention that you can flag for moderator intervention if the questions should be merged, so it's not much of a stretch to infer that you could mod flag in this case too.

Comment: Undeleted one of the identical comments linking to the other question.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha post in question updated https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252017/2756409 - it can be closed again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in chat, [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) handles stuff like this all the time. Feel free to ask in there. Mod flags are slow, and you might not get one who understands the tag you're flagging for.

As I have a PHP hammer, I went ahead and swapped the dupes around as requested.