# Python question about with blocks using several context managers where duplicate > original

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Based on my reading of [Should I flag a question as duplicate if it has received better answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers), it is my understanding I can ask a question here regarding a specific case of duplicate reversal.

[python: create a “with” block on several context managers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3024925/8117067) has been marked as a duplicate of [How can I open multiple files using “with open” in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4617034/8117067). I think the duplication link should be reversed, even though the question currently marked as duplicate was technically asked after the other question (2010 vs. 2009).

The main reason why is that [interjay's accepted answer on the newer question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3025119/8117067) is by far the most comprehensive of all the answers posted between the two questions. It provides vital information about both `contextlib.ExitStack`, a backport of `ExitStack` (!), and the problem with `contextlib.nested` all in one answer. In particular, this vital detail about `Exitstack` may be missed by those who go to the original instead (there *is* an answer about ExitStack in the older question, but it only has 6 upvotes, and is much newer, in fact having been posted by the person who eventually gold-tag badge unilaterally closed the newer question in November of 2018).

I'll also note the newer question is better: it is more generic and general because it asks about handling an arbitrary number of context managers, while the older question asks only about a known number of `open` streams. Because the use of `open` in `with` blocks does not differ from other context managers, they are *indeed* duplicates in their subject material, but the newer question is phrased in a way that fits the exact subject matter better.

**Edit**:

I tried a mod flag to see what would happen. Here's the response I got:

> helpful - This can be taken care of by community members and does not need moderator intervention.

It looks like reversing this is up to the community, or someone with a gold Python tag badge (or a combination of both).

Comment: If you asked a mod to merge the questions then all the answers would appear on the merged question, but only one of the questions would survive. Would doing that make sense?

Comment: Alternatively you could ask Interjay to delete his answer on the current duplicate and write a good answer on the original.

Comment: You can address the gold-badger by posting a @tiimgeb comment on the closed question.

Comment: @RobertLongson Maybe... originally the upvote discrepancy between the two accepted answers was bothering me (the original question's answer had around 500 votes, while Interjay's had around 250 [note I think that says more about the visibility of the questions than the quality of the answers]), but both of them blow any other other answers out of the water (all <60 votes). Does an accepted answer stay accepted after a question merge? Aren't question merges generally reserved for cases when both questions have good answers? Then again, it might be weird for people who see the (continued...)

Comment: ...duplicate target has less upvotes than the older original question marked as a duplicate, but I think most people will at least check the "this is a dupe" link out. I suggested a duplicate reversal because that seemed like the most straightforward and standard solution to problems of this type. Regarding your second idea, I think it makes no sense because then interjay's answer would lose all its visibility, and they would lose a lot of reputation from deleting that answer. @HansPassant I will do that! It completely slipped my mind as a courtesy and possible handling mechanism.