# How to handle duplicate where the closed question has a better answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

In the Reopen Queue, I was given [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54362265/plotting-routes-that-cross-the-international-dateline-using-leaflet-library-in-r) which was marked to reopen because of editing.

I looked at [the marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48857748/mapping-the-shortest-flight-path-across-the-date-line-in-r-leaflet-shiny-using), and the answers there are not very good - one answer says to switch to a different mapping tool (not always an option) and the other is a code-only answer that doesn't explain why it works.

However, the closed duplicate actually has a good answer that explains simply how to solve the problem.

Should the original question be reopened? Is this a case where it would make sense to try to reverse which is the duplicate? Is there some other course of action that should be taken?

Comment: Highly relevant: [Should I flag a question as duplicate if it has received better answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers)

Comment: Your explanation of why the answer is better on the newer question and the answers on the older one not so good was helpful in making a decision in reversing the dupe target. One of the answers on the older post reads like a question.

Comment: @JoshCaswell are you happy with this closed as a dupe?

Comment: I didn't think it was quite a dupe, @YvetteColomb; I actually retracted my close vote. Probably not the end of the world, though.

Comment: @JoshCaswell yeh, I'm in two minds myself, which is why I asked your opinion. It's close.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, if you see a question closed as a duplicate and the closed post is better of the two, raise a custom moderator flag to have the duplication reversed. Give a brief explanation. It's an easy thing for mods to deal with and we do occasionally get flags asking for different dupe targets.

Comment: Are the question's timestamps relevant?

Comment: @JosephQuinsey no, the better question on the merits of the question, but mainly the answers.

Comment: [Should I vote to close a duplicate question even though it's much newer and has more up to date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643) @JosephQuinsey

Comment: Wow, you're a mod so you can post comments on deleted ones, i can't reply tho :-)

Comment: @U9-Forward yeh I know right.  I wanted to explain more than I did in the helpful flag reason. Did I make it clear? I'm not sure I've explained myself well.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Yup, it's clear to me, you explained well, :-)

Comment: @U9-Forward I understood what you were wanting, as  I came directly from this post. I feared that in the future another mod may not understand what you were asking. So I'm glad that's cleared up. :)