# A user deliberately started a duplicate question when an old one was present

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

[A question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111/typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-in-python#comment96909057_31087111) I had answered almost 4 years ago, was marked as duplicate of a [far newer question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740182/im-getting-typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-how-do-i-fix-this-error). I know [it's acceptable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers) to mark older questions as duplicates of newer questions with better responses and I'm okay with that. What makes me a bit concerned is that the author of the newer Q&A, being well aware of the older Q&A (as pointed out in the comments), has deliberately started a new question and answered it instead of adding another answer to the older question and/or editing the question itself. Is such behaviour appropriate? It feels like reputation hoarding to me.

**Update**

I'd like to further explain, why I don't consider such behaviour (in this particular case) acceptable. While I do agree that having a proper MCVE means a lot for a canonical Q&A, the author doesn't seem to be concerned about that. Here is the author's response to another user referencing the question I've answered:

> That's a very valid point you brought up. That answer is pretty good. It's the dupe target I've been using. But there were two main reasons I created this Q&A instead. To put it briefly: : (1) IMHO, the other answer went to in-depth about namespaces and global lookup details, rather than just focusing on the main question. (2) I think it would've been good if the answer had talked a bit more about what built-ins are, to make the post more general. Right now, it just seems to localized.

In other words, the author's main motivation was a subjective opinion about my answer, not the question itself. Moreover, since the author hasn't covered the same topics I have in my post, I will now have to post a copy of my old answer under the canonical Q&A to provide this information, which is frowned upon. I believe that the author should've simply added another answer to the old question, if he/she was dissatisfied with the answers.

**Update 2**

At this point I think the consensus is pretty clear, and it's now time to clean up the mess I've started. We can move this discussion into a separate thread, but I'll start it here.

1. I believe that Christian had no poor intentions, and this whole situation is rather unfortunate. Therefore, I move that all votes cast on his Q&A within the last days should be invalidated (as far as I know the platform provides such capabilities).
2. Since both questions are equivalent (at face value) this makes it necessary to mark one of them as duplicate of the other. And since the question I've answered is already marked as duplicate, I think we can leave it that way. My only concern is the increased likelihood of people missing out on the information I've given in my answer (as it is now posted under a duplicate) that is absent in Christian's answer. Given the number of views and positive votes on the older thread, that information is useful enough to include it in the canonical Q&A Christian has started. I think that he can simply copy my response along with other useful answers from the old thread into his answer and adapt the text to better suit his message and style of writing. I see no need to reference the old thread directly.

Comment: The older question has no MCVE though. If I were to write a detailed explanation like that, I also wouldn't want to post it under a question that requires guessing.

Comment: @ayhan fair enough, though you can always edit the question itself

Comment: Maybe the intention isn't that obvious, although it is mentioned in the comments.  When a google query like "python type error" has 203 million hits then programmers get into trouble, that's too much help.  So a type error question gets asked over and over again, these two "canonicals" help to get them closed.  They are the "dup target".

Comment: @HansPassant shouldn't the answer be a community wiki then?

Comment: No, making an answer with 203 million explanations easy to edit is not a good idea.

Comment: *In this particular case*, I can't condone the creation of a new Q&A. While yes, the original question was lacking a MCVE, the fact that the OP accepted an answer made it perfectly clear what the problem was. The question could simply have been edited into shape. The creation of a new Q&A did 2 things: It showed a massive disrespect for all the effort people had put into writing their answers, and it effectively invalidated all the voting that had taken place on those answers, artificially catapulting Christian Dean's answer to the top. In my opinion, that was **absolutely not ok**.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Some combination of that comment and [the one you posted on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740182/im-getting-typeerror-list-object-is-not-callable-how-do-i-fix-this-error#comment96927142_45740182) would make a good answer.

Comment: I'm a little bit affraid by the voting pattern after this meta post. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45740182/timeline/. See no evil. It's like both poster tryed to make some valuable contribution.

Comment: "It feels like reputation hoarding to me": but Martijn Pieters closed the question as dupe, not Christian, how can it be rep farming? Besides I know Christian's posts and true, there are high-rep rep farmers but he's not one of them.

Comment: It's the meta effect, but there is Nothing to win in a Trial by meta. Once again see no evil. Even if it's not the proper way, I don't believe that there is any bad itention, he just wanted to make a cannonical. We could just try to clean up the mess.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre "how can it be rep farming" – starting a near-identical duplicate of an existing question and positioning his/her answer as something canonical seems pointless to me unless an author wants to see his/her question as the top answer and wants his/her Q&A to be a dupe target, despite adding nothing new to the table. I would've been extremely supportive, had Christian posted the answer under the old question.

Comment: @DragandDrop it's important to recognise, that no one is down-voting the answer, because it is a good post, people are down-voting the question.

Comment: downvoting the question of a canonical self-answer is like downvoting the answer. Maybe Christian could turn his Q&A to community wiki so noone would complain anymore.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the answer is only canonical, because the author has decided to call it that way, so I don't think that making a tight connection between the question and the answer is valid in this case.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Can't we simply join the questions (and all answers) together? I'm not aware of all capabilities this platform offers, so I'm not sure this is possible. In any case, I'm in no way arguing for the removed of Christian's answer. On the contrary, I would object such motion, as I've actually upvoted the answer.

Comment: merging answers is possible with a custom moderator flag IIRC, merging questions isn't, at least not automatically. It looks like it will be difficult to have only one question and make all answers match.

Comment: you already got a lot of upvotes for that answer which is a borderline typo, you should be grateful for that...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't care about upvotes (as is clear from my recent answer record, I tend to answer low-coverage questions). Moreover, my answer is clearly not of the "just fix the typo" kind, implying that is an insult. Somehow, you don't seem to have the same attitude towards the other author. And I don't think you are in any position to tell me, what I should be grateful for. That is plain arrogant and patronising.

Comment: not meant as an insult, I think I already answered such questions in the past, but I didn't get 60+ upvotes (for _any_ answer of mine). That's what I meant by "you should be grateful". Not trying to be patronizing. and I'm defending the other author because what he's subjected to (downvotes in meta and in the question) is too much IMHO. Plus some highrep users have an history of rep farming, he doesn't.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre then again, I'm not concerned about any reputation I might be missing. I've put effort into writing a detailed answer to a question, that could've been dismissed with something simpler, to address a root cause of a recurring problem rather than the consequence. Christian has done the same thing, albeit choosing to focus on a different aspect of the problem. This is why I believe the answers should be located under the same question. By separating them, Christian has created a necessity to mark one of the questions as duplicate, effectively invalidating one of the answers.

Comment: it doesn't invalidate the answers. Sometimes I close questions as duplicates of duplicates because they're closer than the original question. I also get upvotes on duplicates.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't know about other users, but I tend to skip duplicates and go straight for the original.

Comment: It appears that this post is attracting ~~ too much Meta effect. People are probably downvoting the newer question because they don't like the OP's behavior -- even duplicates can be useful as signposts...

Comment: Should we start a new meta post to discuss a way to clean up this mess? I see that people have started down-voting Christian's answer without any good reason to do that, and the whole situation has outgrown anything I've bargained for.

Comment: FYI Eli, since my question has been remarked as a duplicate of yours and my Q&A pair is being nuked, I guess the community has spoken, lol. I'll go ahead and delete my answer. I suppose I might repost my answer on your question.

Comment: @ChristianDean then, go ahead and post it under the old question.

Comment: I was @EliKorvigo, but didn't feel like doing the necessary edits to my answer and the question. My answers posted now, but I still need to re-shape it.

Comment: Alright, my answers up @EliKorvigo. I feel like I was able to re-shape well enough.

Comment: @ChristianDean I've started a bounty to reward your answer and compensate for the reputation you've lost due to the downvotes on the question and removal of the answer. I will award it as soon as the mandatory waiting period runs out.

Comment: Sure @EliKorvigo. Thanks man, I appreciate you wanting to compensate me.

Comment: How has no-one pointed out that the they are both dups of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5735943/692942)? The new dup even references that at the end of their answer.

Comment: @Lankymart because that's not a dupe. The question you've referenced is not about name shadowing, it's about improper subscription syntax, while the questions we've discussed here are both about shadowing a builtin name.

Comment: @EliKorvigo fundamentally `“TypeError: 'list' object is not callable”` is the same error, in that OPs case it wasn't shadowing but for another user looking for that error, it certainly could be. Personally, for an error like that there should be a canonical question and the appropriate answers, yours and Christians included.

Comment: @Lankymart other users urged Christian to cover that case, but he stated (and I agree with him), that the code snippet from that question was pretty clear about the cause of error, i.e. improper syntax. Technically speaking, the question I've answered can be interpreted both ways, because the OP has not included the name-shadowing line in his/her code snippet. I simply inferred the error (as any somewhat experienced Python coder would have). Moreover, the last section from Christian's answer covers the improper syntax case.

Comment: @Lankymart in other words, the older question is almost perfect for the task due to its ambiguity. Nevertheless, if you have a better concept for a universal question, I support the idea.

Comment: @EliKorvigo there is no argument both answers should belong to [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable while trying to access a list](//stackoverflow.com/q/5735841).

Comment: @Lankymart I disagree: that question has a very specific and distinct error case clearly shown in the snippet. Our answers do not belong there. I do agree that we can try to come up with a universal question body, that would cover all common sources of this error message: 1. name shadowing, 2. improper subscription syntax, 3. accidental use of a list instance as a function/callable.

Comment: @EliKorvigo what a weak argument, there is no reason why you can't also have on that question answers like - "Other common reasons for the `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable.` error". That way anyone searching for that specific problem regardless of the original question, get associated information as to why they may also get that error.

Comment: @EliKorvigo take for example this question - [which keyword giving TypeError: 'list' object is not callable](//stackoverflow.com/q/45732952) the OP found the question you answered but their problem wasn't shadowing it was just a syntax problem as is covered in [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable while trying to access a list](//stackoverflow.com/q/5735841). If they had found just this original dup with your answer, Christians etc., they would have likely got the help they needed and not needed to post an obvious dup question.

Comment: @Lankymart in what way is the argument weak. Let's conduct a thought experiment. A user gets this error message and googles it. The user gets to the question you are referencing,  reads the code snippet and sees that it doesn't seem to be his/her case. The user might then try to read the accepted question only to reinforce the feeling, that the thread covers another topic. What is the likelihood of anyone going past the accepted question in that case? Once again, I agree with your proposal to come up with a universal question. Alternatively, we might edit the question if it is appropriate.

Comment: Corrections: "try to read the accepted question" -> "... accepted answer"; "going past the accepted question in that case" -> "the accepted answer"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Having imagined myself hitting the error

```
“TypeError: 'list' object is not callable”
```

I find that **MCVE** is **not so crucial** for such questions: this is the rare case, when I just need to google for the error message, and the answer itself guides me to which things I need to search in my code. Why bother an asker to prepare an MCVE, if the error message itself is sufficient for an answer?

Aside from an MCVE, the difference between the new and old questions is very *superfluous* (e.g., I find that from the beginner's point of view the old question is more "native"), so I **don’t see any reason to create the new question**. And answers for the *new question*, except the [last one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45740229/3440745), are perfectly fit for the *old question*.

---

I also don't think that adding an MCVE into the "old" question would make the question to be better *recognizable* when someone **searches** for the error message.

Currently, the code in the question contains the single line

```
example = list('easyhoss')
```

which I (as a person who has hit the error message and who is searching for it) could almost perfectly recognize:

> Yes, this looks very similar to how I create the list in my code, and the error message points to that line.

Would the question post contain an MCVE like

```
list = ['a', 'b']
example = list('easyhoss')
```

I would still perfectly recognize the last line, but recognizing the first line causes the problems because I don't know **what is important** in that MCVE:

1. Is it crucial that two assignments comes in serial? If yes, then my code doesn't fit for this MCVE, so I need to search another question.
2. Is it crucial that the previous list is created using `[...]` notation? If yes, then my code doesn't fit to it, since I don't use such notation at all.
3. Ok, so I have two lists in the code assigned to different *arbitrary* variables. Do you really want to tell me that this is a problem in Python?!

An MCVE works well when possible answerer tries to understand the problem.
An MCVE works well when one wants to understand the answer. (In that case the answer itself may have its own version of an MCVE.)

But when searching the question for a specific problem, one could match:

1. The line in the code which is pointed by the error message.
2. Some other lines in the code which are **relevant** to the error message according to the **knowledge of the searcher**.

For example, when getting the error message

```
“TypeError: 'my_super_func' object is not callable”
```

even a beginner in Python could understand that definition of their function `my_super_func` is **relevant** to the problem.

But when catching the error message

```
“TypeError: 'list' object is not callable”
```

a beginner does **not** treat assignment to the `list` variable as **relevant**, because from their point of view, the `list()` is a *special function* (or even a language construction) which can be provided only by Python itself.

Yes, after reading the first answer to the question, a beginner's knowledge should expand, so they will treat assignment of a `list` variable to be relevant to the problem. But know it is too late to *recognize the question* - one should try to *recognize the answer* (whether it fits for their actual problem).

Comment: (according to the OP of the new Q&A pair) Although the new answer fits the *question*, it doesn't fit the *asker* (the asker of the first question have some deeper confusion about scoping rules etc.)

Comment: Hm, I have re-read both questions and the self-answer for the new one. And still doesn't find the answer to fit better for the new question than for the old one. Neither question seems to be about scoping rules.

Comment: "I find that MCVE is not so crucial for such question" - if the question you want to ask is "what does this error mean?", then sure; but that is probably best resolved with an English dictionary and some reasoning skills, rather than a search for technical information. If the question you want to ask is "why does this part of the code result in (this error message | an attempt to call a list)?", then an MCVE absolutely is necessary - it would be the result of attempting to debug the code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: "probably best resolved with an English dictionary and some reasoning skills" - Both these skills are not sufficient for resolve even this simple problem in Python without some knowledge of the Python. Moreover, the required knowledge - that any symbol in the Python can be redefined by a user - is not the one which every beginner has. BTW, this is why Stack Overflow is so useful: It allows me to find a receipt which I cannot deduce at my level of understanding of the technology.

Comment: Right, they aren't sufficient to resolve the **problem** in the canonical, that the code shadows the builtin. But that is not the question prompted **directly** by the error message. There are **many other things** that can cause this error, besides shadowing the built-in `list`. For example, erroneously using `()` instead of `[]` to subscript. Which is why a MCVE would be necessary. Otherwise, people with the latter problem will be directed to something useless and misleading (i.e., this canonical, which is a **different question** for the same error message).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: "For example, erroneously using `()` instead of `[]` to subscript. Which is why a MCVE would be necessary." - The question actually **contains code** which is pointed by the error message: `example = list('easyhoss')`. So it is definitely not about subscripting. But that code is **not a MCVE**, because it misses some other line which redefines `list`.

Comment: Sure. But it **should have** an MCVE (and I am discussing the matter [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247434/python-canon-discussion)); and while people looking for it won't necessarily have one, they'd be better off if they'd put in the work to create one. In particular, MCVEs need to be able to work from a new session; so if they'd tried the obvious thing and found that the bug went away, then they'd have the hint that something previous in the session was responsible.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Am I correctly understand that you suggest people who just **search** on SO to create a MCVE? But such requirement doesn't look reasonable. If I face with a strange error message, then my first step is to search for it. If that search gives me a perfect hit, then ... it is great! If that search gives me hundreds of questions, I could read several of them for get *some* understanding of the error and things which could affect on it. Only with that all understanding I could be able to reduce my code to MCVE. (Or I could try to search key things in my complete code).

Comment: No; I'm saying that the question we're talking about should be edited to include an MCVE *so that people who search for it, can see the setup in the question*. Even if they didn't identify the setup properly themselves, they can *recognize* it.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding (my English is not so good), now I get your point. I updated my answer with my thoughts why MCVE doesn't help in *recognition*. During that update I have improved my understanding: It is not MCVE but **relevant code** which helps a person, who searches, to **recognize** their problem in the question post. But "relevance" should be measured **before** reading the **answer**. May be, I will further edit my answer and put "relevance" aspects closer to the beginning of the post.

Answer (score -14):

Since this meta discussion is related to a Q&A post I created, I think it'd be a good idea to give my two cents. Hopefully I can shed some light on my rationale for keeping my Q&A posted and attempt to address your concerns.

> What makes me a bit concerned is that the author of the newer Q&A, being well aware of the older Q&A (as pointed out in the comments), has deliberately started a new question and answered it instead of adding another answer to the older question and/or editing the question itself.

Yes, you're right. I did decide to intentionally create a new Q&A pair, and keep it posted. My reason for doing so was because, after reading your answer *and the question*, I decided that it was appropriate for me to leave my new Q&A pair posted.

The problem in the askers's question was caused because, somewhere in their code, they re-assigned the built-in name `list`. Your answer did address this problem. However, in your subsequent edits, you decided to refocus your answer to primarily explain how python namespaces and scoping work, since it was clear from the askers's comments *that's* where his confusion actually laid. The real reason the asker was having problems was because they misunderstood how Python's namespacing worked.

After observing all of this, it was clear to me that, although yes, I *could* post an answer on the question, and edit the question to suit my answer, it would be better to simply create a new Q&A to *solely* deal with the problem of redefining built-in names; **the question and your answer dealt with a *different, but still very useful topic***. I didn't want to mess it up. So I believed it would be best to leave the question and your answer alone, and create an entirely new post to deal with the *distinct* topic of overwriting built-in names.

> Is such behaviour appropriate? It feels like reputation hoarding to me.

Now, I'd like to be perfectly honest, I'm not trying to pretend that reputation did not play a role in creating my Q&A pair. When I was in the process of considering *creating* a new Q&A post, I obviously had reputation as an incentive. However, the point I'm trying to make, is that reputation was the not the reason why, *after being directed toward your answer*, I decided to keep my Q&A post open. In my view, the question linked and your answer, *while at a glance appearing to deal with overwriting built in names, actually dealt with a different, yet nevertheless helpful, topic*. Because of this, I thought that my Q&A pair was a quality post that dealt with a *distinct, well-defined* problem.

> I'd like to further explain, why I don't consider such behaviour (in this particular case) acceptable. While I do agree that having a proper MCVE means a lot for a canonical Q&A, the author doesn't seem to be concerned about that.

I'm glad you referenced my comment, because I'd like to elaborate on it a bit. When @AndrasDeak originally posted the link to your answer and the question it was responding to, I admit that, while I read the linked post and *I knew* why I thought my new Q&A pair was justified, I didn't take the time to communicate my thoughts in a comment properly. I didn't take the time to flesh out in enough detail a response to @AndrasDeak. While my comment touched upon my reasoning, it didn't elaborate. That's my bad.

> . . . since the author hasn't covered the same topics I have in my post, I will now have to post a copy of my old answer under the canonical Q&A to provide this information . . .

Yes, I know I didn't cover the same topics as you did. Again, that was intentional. As I explained above, the reason for me creating a new Q&A post was because I felt your post and the question you addressed and my Q&A pair had two, ultimately distinct topics. Your answer is great for the topic of the question you were addressing. There's no need to re-post it.

> I believe that the author should've simply added another answer to the old question, if he/she was dissatisfied with the answers.

I understand your perspective. And I can understand why you're frustrated. I understand you feel as if my Q&A post is me reputation hoarding and I'm trying to bump my post to the top. But I feel my reasoning is valid and I have good reason to keep my Q&A up. Nevertheless, if you and community have a reason to disagree, I am willing to delete my Q&A post and repost my answer on the older question.

Comment: You say the two questions deal with different topics. Could you elaborate why you think they're different? To me, they look exactly the same (except one has a MCVE and the other hasn't). What makes you so sure that this question that lacks a MCVE is different from your own question?

Comment: "The question and your answer dealt with a different, but still very useful topic" – with all due respect I fail to see in what way(s) these two questions are different. Our answers are indeed quite different, as we've decided to focus on different aspects of the issue, but that only means that you should've posted your answer under the old question and let users decide, which of them is actually more or less helpful.

Comment: I'd like to make it clear, that I support your desire to address this common source of user errors (as evidenced by the never-ending tide of duplicate questions about this topic), but creating a new nearly-identical question doesn't seem like a real solution to me. At the very least, you should've started a meta-discussion about this topic as recommended by @AlexeiLevenkov.

Comment: Christian, don't delete it. You can convert to community wiki so noone criticizes you for exploiting a "typo". I upvoted both your question & answer when you posted it BTW :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre converting the post to community wiki will not solve one important thing: the existence of this "canonical" Q&A as a dupe target invalidates older answers.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I already did that in my answer. I addressed your question in my first several paragraphs. Do you have a specific question about those paragraphs?

Comment: @EliKorvigo Could you explain how my post 'invalidates' older answers? That seems to be the crux of your problem, no? And to address your previous comments: I explained why I felt the questions were different in my answer. Do you have a specific problem with my reasoning that you'd like to express?

Comment: That was my first thought, @Jean-FrançoisFabre, but I'm afraid that doesn't actually seem like it fixes the problem Eli has.

Comment: the question is a borderline typo anyway. Some could close with "typo" with a comment explaining that you should not use builtins as variable names. Very brave of you to have answered and face an angry mob. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Normally I'd agree, but I feel in this case overwriting a builtin is more than a typo. Sure for more experienced programmers using a builtin name could just be a simple typo, but for new Python users, using a builtin is often a deliberate action. New Python users don't overwrite built-in names because they made a typo, rather, they overwrite builtin names because they don't see anything wrong with it - they don't understand a fundamental concept of Python: builtin names.

Comment: @ChristianDean I'd say new users, coming from other languages, don't understand that builtin names are not reserved and/or in any way different to any other variable names.

Comment: Yeah @EliKorvigo, that's basically my point. The question stems from a user's ignorance, not their mistyping.

Comment: @ChristianDean and that's exactly my point. We've answered the same question, the difference is in what we've inferred to be the root cause. I've figured, that the problem stems from insufficient understanding of name-resolution rules, while you've decided to explain what builtins are in more detail than I have. "I explained why I felt the questions were different in my answer" – your explanation is based on my interpretation of the issue, the question itself allows both interpretations. That's why I didn't find your arguments sufficient and asked for further elaboration

Comment: @ChristianDean "...how my post 'invalidates' older answers?" – for one, the older question is now marked as duplicate and any user will likely simply choose to read the "original". The very reason it is marked as duplicate goes to prove that the questions are identical. The traditional way to choose a better answer is to put them side by side and let the community decide. By separating the answers, you've replaced this democratic mechanism with an authoritarian one – a couple of votes (or even a single one in this case) is sufficient to raise the duplicate flag.

Comment: @EliKorvigo "your explanation is based on my interpretation of the issue, the question itself allows both interpretations" - No. My reasoning is based on the interactions between you and the asker. As I said in my answer, _what the asker said in his comment, made is clear where his confusion actually laid_. My explanation is not based on how you interpreted the question.

Comment: @ChristianDean this goes both ways. If your question will be eventually flagged as duplicate, the answer will be discarded with a greater rate than it should be, despite having a stellar answer. In other words, you've created a situation, where one answer will have to be sacrificed instead of letting both answers live side by side.

Comment: @ChristianDean yes, but those interactions come under my answer, not the question itself. Any new user googling the same error will not be drawn to comments. He or she will be drawn to the question.

Comment: @ChristianDean and since both of our answers address different aspects of the same issue, missing either of them is not going to solve the underlying issue.

Comment: @EliKorvigo I didn't mark your answer as a duplicate, so I can't speak for another user. Honestly, I can understand why you might view having the question marked as a duplicate as unfair. As I stated in this, aswer, I don't see our answers as duplicates. But to address your other objections: Yes, the normal way to judge two answer is to "put them side by side and let the community decide." But my point is that doing so would be incorrect. Our answers address different topics from different questions. Comparing them would be comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: ". . . yes, but those interactions come under my answer, not the question itself. Any new user googling the same error will not be drawn to comments. He or she will be drawn to the question." I think the solution in this case is to reframe the question, so the problem is more clear, and incoming users don't have to waste time.

Comment: @ChristianDean I'm aware that you've attempted to explain the differences between the two questions in your answer, I just wasn't able to follow your explanation. Hence my request for more detail. I understand now that the conversation between Eli Korvigo and the OP of the original question was what made you believe that your question was different. It would be great if you could edit that little bit of very important information into your answer.

Comment: Here's my issue with what you did: The problem with starting your own Q&A was that it is very similar to the original question, because whatever misunderstanding the original OP had, none of it was mentioned in the question itself. At face value, the question asked how to fix an error. It didn't ask "How do builtins work?" or "How do namespaces work?" or anything like that. Explaining namespaces is a nice bonus, but not a requirement for a valid answer. In other words, the question is exactly the same as yours. It is a question about shadowing a builtin, not a question about namespaces.

Comment: @Aran-Fey _"I understand now that the conversation between Eli Korvigo and the OP of the original question was what made you believe that your question was different. It would be great if you could edit that little bit of very important information into your answer."_  I already did mention that in my answer: "since it was clear from the **askers's comments** that's where his confusion actually laid." Is that not clear? Should I rephrase it?

Comment: I'd assume that SO consensus is that we only need to solve whatever inside the question, not the OP's actual problem. If OP wrongly states their problem then they'd have to ask another.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I think I mentally glossed over that part because it sounded like your issue was with Eli's answer: *"However, in your subsequent edits, you decided to refocus your answer to primarily explain how python namespaces and scoping work, since it was clear from the askers's comments that's where his confusion actually laid."* It would probably help if you rephrased this to make it about the *question* rather than the *answer*. Something like "The OP's comments below the accepted answer made it clear that their question was really about namespaces" maybe.

Comment: This looks super reasonable to me, I can't for the life of me understand the downvotes on this answer, nor do I understand the need that some people have to destroy value because of an inferred slight of some sort. Doing anything but leaving both questions open would be a disservice to the internet.

Comment: Yes @TinyGiant, I agree. It seems that the main probably for most is that they felt I gamed the system and unfairly stole reputation that I didn't deserve. I'm afraid I disagree.

Comment: As for the down votes @TinyGiant, this is meta, I'd be worried if I got anything less ;-)

Comment: down voting to discourage this behavior. I have not read guidelines for q&a on stack-overflow. My personal opinion is that this site is like a book each Q&A page is a topic, there should not be multiple pages for a single topic.

Comment: @SheeceGardazi "I have not read guidelines for q&a on stack-overflow. My personal opinion . . ." With all due respect, it would probably be best if you did read Stack Overflow's guidelines. While I most certainly respect your personal opinion, I feel that it's inappropriate to purely use your own personal opinion to guide your actions on Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is a community with set rules. Participating in the community means following _those_ rules, not your own.

Comment: @SheeceGardazi: The whole point of this meta answer is that there are (at least) two sides to this one topic.  Although I think they could best be addressed by separate answers to the same question, especially if one or both answers had a TL:DR summary of what they cover and what the other answer is about.  (Christian, I think it might have been best if you'd edited Eli's answer to add something like that, so beginners could start reading with the answer that addressed their misunderstanding.  Maybe we can get the questions merged, and update the question to include a MCVE.)

Comment: @TinyGiant "Doing anything but leaving both questions open would be a disservice to the internet" – that's the problem here. The coexistence of two identical questions (at least at face value) is barely possible: sooner or later one of the question will be closed as duplicate of the other (as has already happened).

Comment: @EliKorvigo, but they both still exist, right? Also, from the help article on duplicates: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/