# Establishing a canonical for shadowing builtins (especially causing TypeError) in Python

Tags: discussion, specific-question, canonical

### Background

[Feel free to skip this section if you are familiar with Python. I just want to briefly explain the subject matter needed for the canonical - it should be easy to grasp for anyone with general programming experience.]

Like many other programming languages, Python offers a handful of functions (and other "callables" that are not technically functions, but can be used with the same syntax) that are built-in and can be used without and standard library imports or other setup code. Unlike some of those other languages, however, these built-ins are not particularly privileged - in particular, their names are not keywords. Unlike some more of those languages, Python is dynamically typed and treats functions as first-class objects: thus, **it is trivial to rebind these names**, and they can trivially be rebound to things that are not callable. Subsequent attempts to call them, of course, **cause runtime exceptions**:

```
>>> # all of these cause potential problems later:
>>> list = []
>>> str = 'test'
>>> int = 1
```

This is a specific case of *shadowing* in Python. As it happens, the vast majority of built-ins *are* callable, and **overwhelmingly people will cause problems for themselves by assigning non-callables to those names** (as opposed to, say, *different* callables with an incompatible interface).

[That's all you *really* need for the discussion, I think, but here's a bit more advanced material to consider some nuances more finely.]

Of the remainder: in 3.x, `None`, `False` and `True` *do* have special protection, leaving only `Ellipsis` and `NotImplemented`. These are very rarely used, but assigning `NotImplemented` could theoretically cause a lot of different, very strange things to happen. (The literal syntax `...` also evaluates to the initial value of `Ellipsis`, so even code dependent on that value could be rewritten to avoid problems caused by shadowing.)

Therefore, the specific error message caused by *shadowing a builtin* will **almost always look like**:

```
TypeError: 'Foo' object is not callable
```

(where `Foo` is the type of whatever object is shadowing the builtin). However, although the built-in exception classes are callable (instantiating a class in Python is "calling" it), **shadowing an exception would normally cause a different error** (because exceptions are normally *raised* - what some other language call "thrown" - rather than explicitly constructed):

```
>>> IOError = 'Something went wrong reading the file!'
>>> raise IOError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

These errors are rare simply because the names of exceptions are much less tempting for inexperienced programmers to use than names like `list` ("oh, I made a list and can't think of anything descriptive to call it...").

It could also, of course, happen that the name *is* bound to another callable with an incompatible interface:

```
>>> hex(1000)
'0x3e8'
>>> def hex():
...     # we could also demonstrate this using a class,
...     # with yet another slightly different error message.
...     print('curse you!')
... 
>>> hex(1000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: hex() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Conceptually, any name from any outer scope (in particular, the global scope) can be shadowed in the same way, but this is addressed by other canonicals because it ties into more complex issues with variable scoping.

Several details of the above are different in Python 2.x, but not by enough to matter to the discussion (even granting that there are still people who need to write completely new code in legacy codebases).

### The task at hand

I am trying to figure out which of three questions to use as a canonical for this topic, and also make *several* decisions about how to clean up the questions.

#### Candidates

I have recently been using: [Why does code like `str = str(...)` cause a TypeError, but only the second time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605) , because that was the best option I could find last July when I was trying to close yet another question of that type. However, I have my reservations. Even after the extensive work I did on the question (mainly: taking a cue from the top/accepted answer in order to identify the relevant part of a huge original code dump, and distill it to an MRE), the question is framed a little awkwardly. It also focuses on a specific sub-example of how someone might trigger the issue: OP happened to assign the result of a `str` call (which produces a string) to `str`, but it's arguably more common to assign a string literal to `str`. Finally, it has an absolute ton of "personal anecdote" type answers describing how the problem occurs in slightly different scenarios.

I was going through my saves today for a tangentially related reason, and stumbled upon two more candidates:

- [TypeError: 'int' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767391) seems to be another one that a lot of people used to have bookmarked. However, the title is not at all descriptive (it's just the error message, which as I established can be produced in multiple different ways) and it completely lacks an MRE. The cause "somewhere else in the code" was easily identified by several answerers, but still had to be inferred. It has the shortest tail of low-quality answers, but those answers are especially bad in that they're off topic (talking about *distinctly different* causes for the error).
- [Why does "example = list(...)" result in "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111) is one that I recently dupe-hammered to the first because "oh, I have a canonical for this". On a closer read, I think it has the best answers of the three overall. The answer section is much more focused on the actual problem, and the bountied answer is impressive and well deserves the reward (even if there was [some controversy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381064) over how it was originally published on the site). However, the OP again lacks an MRE - although this is somewhat justified by the fact that the question asks about an individual line of code in a REPL session. The Q&A are also both written in a way that might imply that the problem is specific to shadowing the built-in name *with a list*, whereas practically any shadowing value could cause a problem.

#### Decisions to make

My current inclination is to make the last one the canonical - giving it any appropriate [see-also links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419863). Because there doesn't seem to be a clear winner in terms of question metrics, I'd like to achieve consensus here. I also want to decide:

- For the questions that *lack an MRE, should they be edited* so that the code in the question actually reproduces the problem? Or is it sufficient to phrase them like "what could have happened earlier to cause this?" or similar? (I'm worried that this would make such questions look too trivial to passers-by, or motivate "caused by a typo" close votes.)
- Should Stack Overflow have questions like "*What are the possible causes of* <error message>?" If not, can answers describing different causes ever fit in the same answer section?
- Should answer content describing *unrelated causes* for the OP's error message be edited out? Should answers focused *entirely* on an unrelated cause then be deleted?
- If I identify other questions that could work as canonicals for *the same error message, caused a different way* (I think I have [at least one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873727) already), would those make good see-alsos?
- It's relatively rare to shadow an exception. Should that be dealt with in this canonical, or with a separate question?
- Is, for example, ['id' is a bad variable name in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77552) a duplicate, or simply related?

Please also feel free to offer any other suggestions on how to improve these questions.

### Supplemental question

More generally, what should we do in cases where *the same error message is caused by conceptually different problems*? What should we do where *a given conceptual problem can cause multiple different error messages*, depending on details of the setup? What should we do where *both* apply (there is a many-to-many relationship between the problems and errors)? It seems to me that people tend to search based primarily on the error message - because if they knew the cause, they'd just fix the problem. However, if that message could have multiple totally different causes, it will be very hard to get people to find the right Q&A with their search.

Comment: What do you think about closing these as duplicates of: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734399/what-is-variable-shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734399/what-is-variable-shadowing) and adding an answer to this question that gives examples of various errors / issues you could get by shadowing builtin variables?

Comment: IMO it's important that these problems are practically always typo-like; being aware of the actual issue makes a question obsolete. As a result, a canonical likely won't be there for people to find but for us to actively direct people to. I feel the main challenge is that in addition to the somewhat searchable/transferable `x = x()` there are many *syntactical* ways like (`list = []`, `str = ""`, ...) to run into. For example, [your primary candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087111) looks really good in principle but may be hard to apply to other cases.

Comment: FWIW, a very common situation is having obsolete definitions in a notebook that need rerunning specific/all cells even after fixing the error in the source. This is often not covered by answers; not sure if a separate canonical may be needed for this.

Comment: Maybe we need a question that covers this category something like "Why does this built-in name refer to the wrong thing?"

Comment: In principle, I don't object to redirecting all of the candidates to a new canonical. It's just that this is kind of the nuclear option when they all have 6-digit view counts.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat that question looks solid and underappreciated; but it does feel a bit awkward to send people who have a specific, concrete problem in their code to a question about defining a term.

Comment: Could edit one to give it a generally applicable title and write a generally applicable answer to it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel there are too many ways you could get errors by shadowing builtin variables, a generic question that describes the problem would be much better than specific instances of the issue. Similar things are done with other questions as well, for example sometimes people ask about questions about using a server side variable in JavaScript or vice-versa and such questions are commonly closed as duplicates of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: I think the main issue with [TypeError: 'int' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9767391/4284627) and [Why does "example = list(...)" result in "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31087111/4284627) is that they don't have an MRE. In the first one that would be easy to fix by editing to replace `a = 23` with `round = 23` (or possibly `round = 42` in order not to invalidate the accepted answer). Editing the second one to include an MRE might be a bit more difficult, but that might still be preferable since it has better answers.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Any edit would theoretically be against the OP's intent, but OP didn't do the necessary debugging work, but that debugging work is commonly an unreasonable ask for people who actually have the problem. Aside from that, the edit would be trivial in the second case: adding `list = []` before the existing code, for example.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel In the first case I don't think that changing a variable name to make the problem more obvious would conflict with their intent. Obviously adding `list = []` to the code in the second question would be trivial, what I meant was that since it doesn't come naturally it might conflict with the OP's intent more than in the first case where extra variables were already there. But maybe adding `list = []` to the second question should be done anyway since the answers to that question would be good canonical answers.

Comment: I don’t see much point in adding a complete MRE. The entire problem is that people aren’t aware what is the cause; putting the cause in front of the trigger makes the issue *extremely* trivial. Answers *must* explain the cause and that is jarring when the question presents it on a silver plate.

Comment: @Karl I just saw your message on a now-deleted post. I did want to post an answer here, I just keep forgetting, sorry. I'll try to come back soon :)