# What do we do when answering an old question that turns out to be a duplicate of an older question?

Tags: support, questions

[An old question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76028986/13629335) was brought to my attention that I was able to solve, and I wrote an answer.
So far normal, but it turned out to be a duplicate of an [even older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68683393/how-to-unhide-taskbar-on-a-maximized-non-resizable-tkinter-window).

I asked for moderator attention, since (while not much) the older one was more "popular".
The flag was declined, reasoned with:

> Declined - I don't think asking mods to do that is proper. We can't
> tell if it's actually a duplicate and using mod powers to abuse simple
> system checks doesn't sit well with me.

I understand that and now that I gained a single upvote, I was able to flag it as a duplicate.

However, I have run into this issue now more than once. Sometimes I write comments and in a previous case (I can't remember which), I even copy and pasted my answer under the other question.

Is there a proper way to approach this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Age of the question [is not relevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938) for choosing a duplicate.
2. As far as I can tell, the older question is not in any meaningful way "more popular" here. Aside from that, the most important factor is **quality**. The newer question is overall better IMO: it has a proper answer (from you) rather than some off-handed speculation. The older question has a better code example (proper MRE including a `mainloop` call and appropriate imports), but that is easily fixed. Because of this, I went ahead and closed the duplicate from the older one to the newer one.
3. This seems like a commonly enough asked question that a better duplicate could be found. In this case, the duplicate links can be fixed in the future. (I am not a tkinter expert, so I don't know of one.)
4. Do not use mod flags for this. Moderators are almost literally one-in-a-million users (at least, accounts) on Stack Overflow. Question closure is done almost entirely by the community. Instead, simply vote to close (since you have 3000+ reputation) duplicate question as duplicates.

   If you cannot find a duplicate because of the "no upvoted or accepted answer" issue, then **wait**. In the worst case, you can write your own canonical and accept your answer after two days. Alternately, use an appropriate chat room (such as the SOCVR room - [see their website](https://socvr.org/) - or the main Python room, or [my room for discussing/identifying/creating Python canonicals](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247434/python-canon-discussion)) to bring attention to the issue.

Please do not *copy* and paste answers (mods will not be happy), but if there is only one of the questions that *can* be used as a duplicate (or you change your mind about where you should put your answer), consider *cutting* and pasting (i.e., delete the old version first).